# How can I detect pressing Enter on the keyboard using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, enter, jquery-events

I would like to detect whether the user has pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> using jQuery.

How is this possible? Does it require a plugin?

It looks like I need to use the [`keypress()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress) method.

Are there browser issues with that command - like are there any browser compatibility issues I should know about?

Comment: link about this [.keypress() | jQuery API Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress)

Comment: One of the best things in Javascript frameworks is that they should be by default cross-browser compatible. They handle the browser compatibility checks so that the user doesn't have to. I haven't read the JQuery source code but I doubt the keypress functionality is any different in that sense.

Comment: the only browser compatibility issue is that you should use e.which instead of e.keyCode to detect the ascii code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed

Answer (score 1501, accepted):

The whole point of jQuery is that you don't have to worry about browser differences. I am pretty sure you can safely go with <kbd>enter</kbd> being 13 in all browsers. So with that in mind, you can do this:

```
$(document).on('keypress',function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm linking to this because I read this and left scratching my head over why keypress didn't work with IE. (it won't bind to `$(window)` under IE) http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Comment: e.keyCode is not 100% cross browser. use e.which instead as shown below

Comment: From the jQuery documentation "The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input."

Comment: $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {

Comment: I'm getting multiple executions of the given function due to event propagation (ie, the alert is being thrown twice). To stop this, add an e.stopPropagation() at the end of the function

Comment: The Jquery documentations says 
Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

so unless you have an issue with keydown, why not use the one that is official

Comment: I'm also getting multiple executions of the given function  (ie, the alert is being thrown twice). I already add an e.stopPropagation() at the end of the function but nothing happens

Comment: $(document).keypress(function(e) {if(e.which === 13) {
    $("form").submit();
   }
  });

Comment: A list and an interactive key code generator is available at http://www.javascriptkeycode.com/. Useful if you want a key code and don't already know the numeric value it corresponds to.

Comment: As seen in one of the answers below, I needed to use the 'keydown' event, keypress did not work in Chrome for me.

Comment: Always use `===` to prevent unexpected type coercion.

Comment: should be 'keydown'

Answer (score 143):

I wrote a small plugin to make it easier to bind the "on enter key pressed" event:

```
$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
            var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                fnc.call(this, ev);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
$("#input").enterKey(function () {
    alert('Enter!');
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (i got `#input` on the `<input>` field)

Comment: What about if #input element will be dynamic?

Comment: @mplungjan not sure what you mean by "delegating"

Comment: `$("#input").on("someevent","someselector",function () {})`

Answer (score 71):

I couldn't get the code posted [by Paolo Bergantino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-can-i-detect-pressing-enter-on-the-keyboard-using-jquery/979686#979686) to work, but when I changed it to `$(document)` and `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode` then I found it to work faultlessly.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed Enter!');
    }
});
```

[Link to example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/atuse5)

Comment: For me e.which does not work with IE. Does it work for others?

Comment: Which version of IE? Works fine for me on IE7.

Comment: From the jQuery documentation "The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input."

Answer (score 56):

I found this to be more cross-browser compatible:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if(keycode == '13') {
        alert('You pressed a "enter" key in somewhere');    
    }
});
```

Comment: Your Ternary IF can be shortened to:
var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;

Comment: For buttons inside forms, I put this line before the alert (or the action):
event.preventDefault();
It prevents the form submission.

Answer (score 43):

You can do this using the jQuery 'keydown' event handler:

```
$("#start").on("keydown", function(event) {
  if(event.which == 13)
    alert("Entered!");
});
```

Comment: I use this answer because of I need to check from specific input id. Thanks

Comment: Since it's a keydown, I am paranoid this will multi-trigger if the user holds the enter keypressed. Usually I prefer keyup. For some use cases this might be required though. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 26):

#### Use `event.key` and modern JavaScript!

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Or without jQuery:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function onEvent(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // Do something better
    }
});
```

[Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Answer (score 9):

I came up with this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#loginforms').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    alert('login pressed');
    }
  });

 $('#signupforms').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      //e.preventDefault();
      alert('register');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You ought to spend some time explaining your solution. An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27771911/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 7):

There's a [keypress()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress) event method. The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key's ASCII number is 13 and is not dependent on which browser is being used.

Answer (score 7):

A minor extension of [Andrea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-can-i-detect-pressing-enter-on-the-keyboard-using-jquery/9964945#9964945) makes the helper method more useful when you may also want to capture modified enter presses (i.e., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>). For example, this variant allows binding like:

```
$('textarea').enterKey(function() {$(this).closest('form').submit(); }, 'ctrl')
```

to submit a form when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> with focus on that form's textarea.

```
$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc, mod) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
            var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
            if ((keycode == '13' || keycode == '10') && (!mod || ev[mod + 'Key'])) {
                fnc.call(this, ev);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

(See also *[Ctrl + Enter using jQuery in a TEXTAREA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684196/ctrlenter-jquery-in-textarea*.))

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, you may need to suppress the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key for a certain area of a page but not for other areas of a page, like the page below that contains a **header** `<div>` with a *SEARCH* field.

It took me a bit to figure out how to do this, and I am posting this simple yet complete example up here for the community.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Test Script</title>
  <script src="/lib/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.container .content input').keypress(function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Form Submission needs to occur using the Submit button.');
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="FileSearch">
          <!-- Other HTML here -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <form id="testInput" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text1" />
        <input type="text" name="text2" />
        <input type="text" name="text3" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Link to JSFiddle Playground](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/W2xFX/42/): The `[Submit]` button does not do anything, but pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from one of the Text Box controls will not submit the form.

Comment: But an explanation would be in order. How does it work? By some DOM magic? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20339685/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). work?

Answer (score 4):

As the `keypress` event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode || event.which === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Call function, trigger events and everything you want to do. Example: Trigger the button element with a click
    $("#btn").trigger('click');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" onclick="console.log('Button Pressed.')">&nbsp</button>
```

Comment: To note, the reason to why `keypress` isn't in spec (anymore) is that it's been deprecated ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event)).

Answer (score 3):

Try this to detect the Enter key pressed.

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        alert("You've pressed the enter key!");
    }
});
```

See demo @ [detect enter key press on keyboard](http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-detect-enter-key-press-on-keyboard-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 2):

I used `$(document).on("keydown")`.

On some browsers `keyCode` is not supported. The same with `which` so if `keyCode` is not supported you need to use `which` and vice versa.

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  const ENTER_KEY_CODE = 13;
  const ENTER_KEY = "Enter";
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which
  var key = e.key
  if (code == ENTER_KEY_CODE || key == ENTER_KEY) {
    console.log("Enter key pressed")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
      //proper indentiation of keycode and which to be equal to 13.
    if ( (event.keyCode || event.which) === 13) {
        // Cancel the default action, if needed
        event.preventDefault();
        //call function, trigger events and everything tou want to dd . ex : Trigger the button element with a click
        $("#btnsearch").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to detect whether the user has pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> is to use the key number. The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key number is equal to 13.

To check the value of key in your device:

```
$("input").keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 32 || (65 <= e.which && e.which <= 65 + 25)
                    || (97 <= e.which && e.which <= 97 + 25)) {
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $("p").append($("<span/>"))
          .children(":last")
          .append(document.createTextNode(c));
  } else if (e.which == 8) {
    // Backspace in Internet Explorer only is on keydown
    $("p").children(":last").remove();
  }
  $("div").text(e.which);
});
```

By pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you will get result as 13. Using the key value, you can call a function or do whatever you wish:

```
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
        console.log("The user pressed the Enter key");

        // The code you want to run
      }
    });
```

If you want to target a button once the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, you can use the code:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
  if(e.which === 13) { // Return
     $('#buttonname').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method would be using [vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
   if (event.key === 13){
     alert("Enter was pressed");
   }
}
```

Comment: But the question said *"I would like to detect whether the user has pressed Enter using jQuery."* Why is this an appropriate solution anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This my how I solved it. You should use `return false;`

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('#sub_btn').trigger('click');
        alert('You pressed the "Enter" key somewhere');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post" id="sub_email_form">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" id="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Subscribe to our Technical Analysis</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Signup for our regular Technical Analysis updates to review recommendations delivered directly in your inbox.</p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" name="sub_email" id="sub_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
        </div>
        <span id="save-error"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sub_btn" id="sub_btn" name="sub_btn" value="Subscribe">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example of how you can do it easily. Imagine you want to detect keystrokes from the website's body area,

```
$("body").keypress(function(event) {
    console.log("This key got pressed - " + event.key);
});
```

This will display the result in the console as "This key got pressed" + the key you pressed in the keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.key === 'Enter') {
        //Do the stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks like an adaption of other answers - could you add some explanation to make yours as interesting as the others?

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function(){
  $('.modal-content').keypress(function(e){
    debugger
     var id = this.children[2].children[0].id;
       if(e.which == 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#"+id).click();
       }
   })
});
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanatory comments to explain the asker how your code works - thanks.