# Ctrl + Enter using jQuery in a TEXTAREA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hotkeys

How do I trigger something when the cursor is within *TEXTAREA* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed?

I am using jQuery.

Comment: the answer you accepted does not work. Please change your accepted answer

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can use the [`event.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.ctrlKey) flag to see if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed. Something like this:

```
$('#textareaId').keydown(function (e) {

  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
    // Ctrl + Enter pressed
  }
});
```

Check the above snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/ovowu).

Comment: This does not work in Google Chrome. When Ctrl + Enter is pressed the key code is `10`, not `13`.

Comment: This does not work. Yarolslav Yakovlev's solution below does work properly. Please change accepted answer to save people time.

Comment: @Replete Which environment have you tested? Is there any documentation about keyCode 10?

Comment: keyCode 10 shouldn't happen anymore on Chrome, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79407

Comment: when trigger `keypress` event, the keycode will be 10, but `keydown` or `keyup` will report 13. Only test chrome

Answer (score 158):

Actually this one does the trick and works in all browsers:

```
if ((event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) && event.ctrlKey)
```

Link to [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLyMJ/10/).

Notes:

- In Chrome on Windows and Linux, <kbd>Enter</kbd> would be registered as `keyCode` 10, not 13 ([bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79407)). So we need to check for either.
- [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) is <kbd>control</kbd> on Windows, Linux and macOS (not <kbd>command</kbd>). See also [`metaKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey).

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work in Firefox 27, what's wrong?

Comment: Just call add `event`: `if ((event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) && event.ctrlKey)`

Comment: @Yaroslav : Can you please tell what is the use of "event.keyCode == 10" in you answer.

Comment: @Shashank.gupta40 From the answer that is marked as the answer: This does not work in Google Chrome. When Ctrl + Enter is pressed the key code is 10, not 13

Comment: If anyone still wondering about keyCode 10 and other chrome stuff read [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79407).

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev does `ctrlKey` correspond to the Command key on Macs?

Comment: That Chrome bug has long been fixed apparently, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79407

Comment: To support Mac too: ```if ((e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13) && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey))```

Answer (score 113):

**Universal solution**

This supports macOS as well: both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will be accepted.

```
if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 10)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Don't ignore this answer because it's got a lower score, it's just a newer answer, it's actually better.

Comment: Explanation of first part: On macOS, `e.ctrlKey` detects `⌃ Control` and `e.metaKey` detects `⌘ Command`. Use this if you want both Ctrl-Enter and Command-Enter to trigger the behavior.

Comment: Can you explain why you accept a `e.keyCode` of `10` to mean Enter in addition to `13`? The [MDN `keyCode` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) lists only `13` as a possible value for Enter, tested across multiple browsers and operating systems.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Some versions of Chrome on Windows and Linux use the value 10, apparently.

Answer (score 5):

I found answers of others either incomplete or not cross-browser compatible.

This code works in Google Chrome.

```
$(function ()
{
    $(document).on("keydown", "#textareaId", function(e)
    {
        if ((e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13) && e.ctrlKey)
        {
            alert('Ctrl + Enter');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you consider improving your answer by adding further explanations? Thanks :) Otherwise this would just be a low quality answer to a low quality question.

Comment: @Valamas : Can you please tell what is the use of "event.keyCode == 10" in you answer.

Comment: I love copy & paster answers

Answer (score 2):

This can be extended to a simple, but flexible, jQuery plugin as in:

```
$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc, mod) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
            var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
            if ((keycode == '13' || keycode == '10') && (!mod || ev[mod + 'Key'])) {
                fnc.call(this, ev);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Thus

```
$('textarea').enterKey(function() {$(this).closest('form').submit(); }, 'ctrl')
```

should submit a form when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> with focus on that form's textarea.

(With thanks to *[How can I detect pressing Enter on the keyboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-can-i-detect-pressing-enter-on-the-keyboard-using-jquery/9964945#9964945)*)

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting that `keyCode` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

You can use:

```
if((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.key === "Enter")
```

Which works on both Mac and Windows.

Using React + TS it looks something like this:

```
const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
     if((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.key === "Enter"){
         //do something
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.keyCode` and `event.which` are deprecated.

The following works to handle `CTRL/Command + Enter` on Mac and Windows *(React)*

```js
import React from "react";

export const Component = () => {
    const keyDownHandler = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.key == "Enter") {
            // handle Ctrl/Command + Enter
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <textarea onKeyDown={keyDownHandler} />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set a flag when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed; do this onkeydown.

Then you have to check the keydown of <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Unset the flag when you see a keyup for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: There's no need for this. `KeyboardEvent` already contains properties that indicate whether a key was pressed while `Ctrl` was being held or not, for example. There is no need for manual detection of the `Ctrl` key.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('my_text_area').focus(function{ set_focus_flag });

//ctrl on key down set flag

//enter on key down = check focus flag, check ctrl flag
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late to the game, but here is what I use. It will also force submit of the form that is the current target of the cursor.

```
$(document.body).keypress(function (e) {
    var $el = $(e.target);
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 10) {
        $el.parents('form').submit();
    } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
        $el.parents('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: You could simplify the “`if`…`else if`” to a single `if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13))`.