# Catch Ctrl+Enter when the user types text in Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor

Tags: javascript, extjs4, html-editor

I'm trying to make an [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> while entering text in *Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor (xtype:'htmleditor')*, but I don't know how to do it.

I got a button next to the 'htmleditor' which can send the value of the 'htmleditor', but I'd like to add a keyboard shortcut for that operation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It need to be made with [Ext JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS) 4 - somehow I **must add something like 'keypress' listener** to my htmleditor object...

Here is the code...

```
this.htmleditor = this.addComment.add({
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'htmleditor',
    margin: '0 0 0 0',
    enableSourceEdit: false,
    height: 200
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot listen for events in the default htmleditor. So you need use an updated version of it.

This code can help you (it is for Ext JS 3, so maybe you need change it for version 4):

```
Cyber.ui.HtmlEditor = Ext.extend(Ext.form.HtmlEditor, {
        frame : true,
        initComponent : function() {
            Cyber.ui.HtmlEditor.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
            this.addEvents('submit');
        },
        initEditor : function() {
           Cyber.ui.HtmlEditor.superclass.initEditor.call(this);
            if (Ext.isGecko) {
                Ext.EventManager.on(this.doc, 'keypress', this.fireSubmit,
                        this);
            }
            if (Ext.isIE || Ext.isWebKit || Ext.isOpera) {
                Ext.EventManager.on(this.doc, 'keydown', this.fireSubmit,
                        this);
            }
        },
        fireSubmit : function(e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey && Ext.EventObject.ENTER == e.getKey()) {
                // Do what you need here
            }
        }
});

Ext.reg('customeditor', Cyber.ui.HtmlEditor);
```

And in your form:

```
this.htmleditor = this.addComment.add({
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'customeditor',
    margin: '0 0 0 0',
    enableSourceEdit: false,
    height: 200
});
```

---

I played a lot with Ext JS 4 and found the way (you need just include this code before you'll use htmleditor):

```
Ext.form.HtmlEditor.override({
    frame : true,
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callOverridden();
        this.addEvents('submit');
    },

    initEditor : function() {
        this.callOverridden();

        var me = this;
        var doc = me.getDoc();

        if (Ext.isGecko) {
            Ext.EventManager.on(doc, 'keypress', me.fireSubmit, me);
        }

        if (Ext.isIE || Ext.isWebKit || Ext.isOpera) {
            Ext.EventManager.on(doc, 'keydown', me.fireSubmit, me);
        }
    },

    fireSubmit : function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && Ext.EventObject.ENTER == e.getKey()) {
            // Do what you need here
            alert('yes!');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It "brokes" some parts of the htmleditor... and It freeze (insteat of alert()) when I press ctrl+enter... so I think that maybe that will help, but I have never worked with extjs3 and I'm pretty new to extjs4 so can You help me with conversion?

Comment: @T1000 - I have updated my answer, so you can try correct version for extjs4.

Comment: Thanks, the last one works well for me, very useful!  I also use: var content = Ext.getCmp('htmlEd').textareaEl.dom.value; to get the value of the htmlEditor.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684196/ctrlenter-jquery-in-textarea) may be what you're after (was already on Stack Overflow): *[Ctrl + Enter using jQuery in a TEXTAREA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684196/ctrlenter-jquery-in-textarea)*:

```
$('#textareaId').keydown(function (e) {
e = e || event; // For compatibility with Internet Explorer (I believe)
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
    // Ctrl + Enter pressed
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but... I forgot to note that It must be done with extjs... can not be done with jQuery and I'm not using #IDs anywhere (so getElementById() is also useless). htmlEditor object is assignet to variable in the main object... something like this.htmlEditor.   So I need to get keypress event for this.htmlEditor but there is no keypress event in the events of xtype:htmleditor

Comment: Ah. Hmmm, can you modify the textarea HTML element? You could just do `<textarea onkeydown="javascript:checkKeys()"></textarea>`
`function checkKeys() { var e = window.event; if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) runAjax(); }` Edit: ah I see o_O nevermind then, sorry! Those two other replies might know more about it :p

Comment: It is NOT a textarea It is extjs4's Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for Ext JS 6 (the example disables the Enter key):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.HtmlEditor', {
    width: 580,
    height: 250,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners:{
       initialize: function(editor){
           const doc = editor.getDoc();
           const docEl = Ext.get(doc);
           docEl.on({
              keypress: (e)=>{
                if (e.event.code === 'Enter'){
                  e.preventDefault();
                }
              },
              delegated:false,
              scope: editor
           });
       }
    }
});
```