# Increase height of htmlEditor on change in extJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new in extJS 4 and I've following problem. I don't want to have scrollbar in htmlEditor component, so I'd like increase height of htmlEditor automatically, when new line comes. I have no idea, how to do this. I tried to do something with change lisnener, but without effects. Is there any option to get number of inserted lines?

Comment: You might be able to do something with the [`render`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor-event-render) or [`afterrender`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor-event-afterrender) event and their [`textareaEl`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8411540/1253609) object.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think of doing this is using the Ext.util.TextMetric (I think that's it).  Now measuring total width of your htmlEditor component and increasing height by an amount for ever new factor of your htmlEditor component width.

I know you specifically state that you don't want a scrollbar, but a static scrollbar that is always present vs a appearing and reappearing one actually looks pretty nice.  This way you don't get shifting elements when the scrollbar appears etc.