# textarea control - custom behavior enter/ctrl+enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following simple `<textarea>`

```
<textarea id="streamWriter" rows="1" cols="20" placeholder="Writer"></textarea>
```

Also I have the following jQuery/JavaScript code block:

```
$('textarea#streamWriter').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            alert('ctrl enter - go down a line as normal return would');
            return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('submit - not your default behavior');
    }
});
```

I'm trying to force the  not to create a new line break on normal return keydown. But I want this behavior if Ctrl+Enter was typed instead.

This does detect the difference but is not forcing the behavior that I need.
If you've used Windows Live Messenger, I need the same textbox behavior. Enter to submit (In my case I will call a function but stop the textarea from going down a line) and Ctrl+Enter go down a line.

Solutions? Thanks.

## Update:

```
$('textarea#streamWriter').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            //emulate enter press with a line break here.
            return true;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div#writerGadgets input[type=button]').click();
    }
});
```

The above does what I am trying to do. There is just the part to emulate enter press with a line break. Please let me know how to do this if you know.

Comment: e.preventDefault in a keydown will not prevent the new line break in chrome. That was the purpose of the keypress event handler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `keypress` instead of `keydown` works a little better, however will not work with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key; I switched to the <kbd>shift</kbd> key - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYxUE/).

<strike>Edit: As far as I can tell, you won't be able to use Ctrl key consistently cross browser because the browser uses it for it's own short-cuts. You would run into the same situation with the alt key.</strike>

Edit again: I have a solution that works with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYxUE/2/).

```
$('textarea#streamWriter').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.ctrlKey) {
        //console.log("enterKeyDown+ctrl");
        $(this).val(function(i,val){
            return val + "\n";
        });
    }
}).keypress(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('submit');
        return false;  
    } 
});
```

Edit: This doesn't work 100%, it only works if you are not in the middle of text. Gonna have to work on a way to have the code work on text in the middle.

**By the way...** Why are you doing it this way? Wouldn't it be confusing to the user if they pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> to make a new line and the form all of a sudden submitted before they were ready?

Comment: Slack does this way too: `enter` submits instead of a newline. Hard to break the habit. Fortunately, Slack lets you edit your messages after sending. Needed.

Answer (score 4):

Clear [VanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com):

```
document.querySelector('#streamWriter').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // Ctrl + Enter
        if(e.ctrlKey) {
            console.log('ctrl+enter');

        // Enter
        } else {
            console.log('enter');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Kevin B's solution works well on Mac, but not on windows.

On windows, when <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed, the keyCode is 10 not 13.

[Ctrl+Enter jQuery in TEXTAREA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684196/ctrlenter-jquery-in-textarea?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Modern Javascript should avoid keyCode unless better alternatives are not available on your target browser. KeyboardEvent.code is a better direct replacement, or KeyboardEvent.key if you care about the generated character more.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code