# Adding filter to select multiple rows using Ctrl key in Firefox but in Chrome it's working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to select multiple rows using the Ctrl key then the border of the selected `td` is blue.

I am using this code to check whether the Ctrl key is pressed or not:

```
$("#unSelectedTab td").click(function (event) {

        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            $(this).toggleClass("backgroundcolor");
        }
        else {
            $("#unSelectedTab td").removeClass("backgroundcolor");
            $(this).addClass("backgroundcolor");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I made that code working by adding a css property
` 
table 
{
        -moz-user-select: none;
    }
`

Comment: use this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery

change the selector as u need

Comment: @PrinceChopra Could you answer your own question and then later accept it? So that others can find the solution easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

Migth be:
event.browserEvent.ctrlKey

You should put a breakpoint in Firebug and see what properties event has.