# JavasctiptMVC keypress event

Tags: keypress, javascriptmvc

My work in JavascriptMVC is capturing the enter press event and i have steal ('jquery/event/key') plugin and my code is

```
'input keypress': function(ev){
alert("inside");
alert(ev.key());
if(ev.key() == '\r') {
alert("enter");
}
},
```

but it doesn't work in firefox itself my first alert('inside') is working but after that it says "ev.key() is not a function". Can anyone help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed

Answer (score 0):

What object is ev? Isn't 'key' a property instead? Maybe this will help [How to detect pressing Enter on keyboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)