# How can a parameter that hasn't been defined previously be used?

Tags: jquery, function, variables, parameters, arguments

I have seen this being used through multiple languages so it seems to be just a coding question in general.
On [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979686/3335315) here at stackoverflow, it seems as though he used a variable as a parameter, but e has not been defined before this function.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

What is happening with "e" in situations like this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? e is the parameter of the function and the code that calls it will pass an argument.

Comment: Seeing as how this is javascript, the function parameter is actually defined `e`, it's just not strongly typed

Comment: I'd like to know how it knows what information e is giving the function. Would it be the context of how it is used? .which listens for events, so would that mean that e is used to listen for all key and mouse events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function(e)` actually is a callback. `e` has been initialised somewhere in the jQuery library and inserted into the anonymous function's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

"e" is the event handler and holds further information about the specific event that you trapped.