# How to Combine Two Different Trigger Events using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following events that can occur on two different fields but on the subject field, apart from also triggering a change event, I would also like to catch if the user presses the enter key instead of the tab key, i.e.:

```
$("#P300_FILE_NAME,#P300_SUBJECT").change(function(){
   ... do some processing ....
});
```

Now from another thread here in SO, I found the following code snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery), i.e.

```
$("#P300_SUBJECT").enterKey(function () {
```

that works a treat when the enter key is pressed but I would like to incorporate it as part of the above change event code processing, where it can either check if the user pressed the tab key on the subject field or pressed the enter key instead.

Unsure how I can combine the two events in order to perform the necessary "...do some processing ..." code.

It's almost like I need something like:

```
$("#P300_FILE_NAME,#P300_SUBJECT").change(function() || $("#P300_SUBJECT").enterKey(function () {
```

Comment: this might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foo = function () {
  // Put your code here.
}


$("#P300_FILE_NAME,#P300_SUBJECT").change(foo);
$("#P300_SUBJECT").enterKey(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind an event handler which is triggered on multiple different events. In this case, you want to trigger the event on `change` and on `keypress`. I don't think there's an `enterKey` event, so I'm not sure where that came from, as it doesn't appear to be a jQuery method either.

```
$("#P300_FILE_NAME, #P300_SUBJECT").on("change keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.type == "keypress" && 
       ($(this).is("#P300_FILE_NAME") || e.which != 13) {
        return false;
    }
    ....
});
```

Comment: `enterKey` is not the name of an event.

Comment: But, it should not fire on `enter key` of `#P300_FILE_NAME`. I think, separating both will be a better option.

Comment: @Jashwant Maybe, or just make the `if` more specific rather than having a separate handler...