# Adding "enter trigger" for submission

Tags: jquery

I'm currently learning javascript and jquery. I'm having a little trouble implementing "enter button" functionality once the text field has been filled. As of right now it only works when I click the button. I would really like to be able to hit enter and have the list item submitted. I'm working with a basic UL. Here's my code and I hope that was clear!

```
$('#addOne').submit(function(e) {
    var value = $('#name').val();
    $('ul').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: Can you post the html please

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect pressing enter on keyboard using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)

Comment: You may want to do a bit of research about how to track when the enter key is pressed. The top item under Related to the right seems like a good place to start :).

Answer (score 0):

By default the browser executes the submit event when the user hit enter in some field of form.
Can you show me the page where you have that problem?

Comment: honestly i was just playing around in jsbin its not a live application. I guess i should be more clear on what im doing. Its not actually a submit form button. I just want to append the ul list with what I entered in the text field to be displayed on the webpage.

Comment: $("#addOne").on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {} // enter keycode
    });