# javascript redirect isnt working

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that takes a users input and redirects to a the window to a URL with their input appended to the end.

Here is my HTML

```
        <form id="wikiForm">
            <label id="sideBarLabel">VoIP Services
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Wiki: e.g. E911" name="queryString" id="query-string" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="searchWiki();" />
        </form>
```

The javascript it runs

```
function searchWiki() {
    alert("Form Works!");
    var siteQuery = $('#query-string').val();
    window.location.href = "http://wiki.voipinnovations.com/dosearchsite.action?queryString=" + siteQuery;
    alert("SECOND MESSAGE");
}
```

The issue is that it does not redirect. It only appends the 'siteQuery' variable to the end of the current URL. I know its calling the javascript because I see both alerts. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There reason is because you using `type="submit"`, which submits and sends an GET header to the default `action` parameter (current page).

Change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

```
<form id="wikiForm">
    <label id="sideBarLabel">VoIP Services
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Wiki: e.g. E911" name="queryString" id="query-string" />
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchWiki();" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function searchWiki() {
        alert("Form Works!");
        var siteQuery = $('#query-string').val();
        alert(siteQuery);
        window.location.assign("http://wiki.voipinnovations.com/dosearchsite.action?queryString=" + siteQuery);
        alert("SECOND MESSAGE");
    }
</script>
```

I tried the code with `type="submit"` and it's alerting, but not redirecting, because the submit is prioritized before the `window.location` change, thats the reason it just appends a `?queryString=value` to the current url.
If you change the type like showed in the code above, it's working perfectly.

Comment: This is good. But can you explain to me why my form doesnt submit when you press enter on keyboard with this form? It only works when you actually click on the button. When you hit enter, it appends the 'queryString' to the current URL and refreshes the page.

Comment: Because you using an `onclick`-Event handler. You could remove the `<form>` and just using javascript for the whole process, because you are not using the GET/POST for your self, but for the redirect url. This will prevent it from submiting. Than you can do a `keypress`-Event on  `window` or the button and use it. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the fact that you're actually submitting your form, and the redirection is lost as the form submission occurs first. There are two easy ways to fix this:

1. Change the type of the input from `submit` to `button`, OR
2. Stop the submission of the form by returning false from your function and changing the call of the function to `onclick="return searchWiki();"`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z6spx8hn/)** (1)

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sucy1qwh/1)** (2)

Comment: This is great but can you tell me why it doesnt work when you hit the enter button? Yours does the same thing mine does... refresh the page. When i click search it works but when I hit enter it doesnt.

Comment: So you want hitting the enter key to trigger the redirection, or you don't? When a form has a single text input, the default behavior when hitting enter on it is to submit the form.

Comment: Right but the weird thing is that it isnt doing that for me. I want hitting the enter key to trigger the redirection. But the redirection only works when I click the submit button. I dont understand why this is.

Comment: Right because either way you're essentially bypassing the form's submit event in order to run your JavaScript. You could attach an event handler to the input box to check on keypresses whether the enter key was pressed and if so, run the same redirection code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use assign?

```
window.location.assign("http://wiki.voipinnovations.com/dosearchsite.action?queryString=" + siteQuery);
```

Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: Tried that. Has the same results.

Comment: Is there any error in the console - can't see why that wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

### Use default `action` and `method` attributes instead

The HTML form element provides the mechanism for doing this out of the box.

```
<form id="wikiForm" action="http://wiki.voipinnovations.com/dosearchsite.action" method="GET">
    <label id="sideBarLabel">VoIP Services
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Wiki: e.g. E911" name="queryString" id="query-string" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**But, if you must use javascript, make this change:**

*From:*

```
window.location.href = "…";
```

*To:*

```
window.location.assign("…"); // or
window.location = "…"
```

This is because `location.href` is a read-only property and `location.assign()` is the proper method for setting the new location to be loaded. You may also directly assign a string to the `location` object:

> Whenever a new value is assigned to the location object, a document
>   will be loaded using the URL as if location.assign() had been called
>   with the modified URL.

*Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)*

Answer (score 0):

Change input type=submit to type=button

http://plnkr.co/edit/w4U7Sbm3XSKN8j3zUFMe?p=preview

```
<form id="wikiForm">
    <label id="sideBarLabel">VoIP Services
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Wiki: e.g. E911" name="queryString" id="query-string" />
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchWiki();" />
</form>
```