# Run javascript function when enter is pressed - JavaScript only no Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am trying to run a javascript function when I press enter.
Here is my code so far

**MY HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form id="inputForm">
            <label for="userInput">Input : </label>
            <span id="userInputSpan">
                <input type="text" id="userInput" onkeydown="readInput(this)" />
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**MY JAVASCRIPT**

```
function readInput(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { // 13 is enter key
        // Execute code here.
        // var temp = e.value;
        // console.log(temp);
        alert(e.value);
    }
}
```

Here is my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/razazizewe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect pressing enter on keyboard using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)

Comment: @KevalBhatt I am not allowed to use Jquery unfortunately . . Jquery would make life so much easier if I were allowed to use it :(

Comment: What is the reason for not being allowed to use jquery?

Comment: @MorganGreen it is just the assignment requirement :) I was stuck with this issue, hence I asked :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing `this` to the event handler and using it as `event` object.

Pass the element instance and event object to the event handler.

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" onkeydown="readInput(this, event)" />
                                                       ^^^^  ^^^^^
```

And get them in the handler

```
function readInput(el, e) {
                   ^^  ^
// el: Element
// e: Event object
```

[**Updated JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/sutoporalu/1/edit?html,js,output)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("userInput").focus();
};

function readInput(el, e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log(el.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="inputForm">
    <label for="userInput">Input :</label>
    <span id="userInputSpan">
      <input type="text" id="userInput" onkeydown="readInput(this, event)"/>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

**Suggestions:**

1. Use [**DOMContentLoaded**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event instead of using onload.
2. Use [**addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to bind event
3. To set focus on page load, use `autofocus` attribute on input
4. To prevent `form` from submit, use `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` from event handler.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('userInput').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log(this.value);
      
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action i.e. submit form
      // return false;
    }
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="inputForm">
    <label for="userInput">Input :</label>
    <span id="userInputSpan">
      <input type="text" id="userInput" autofocus />
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect, also I am guessing e is for event and el is for element ? :)

Comment: @gkmohit yes...you can check the key code with e.keyCode and any manipulation on the element using el.

Comment: @gkmohit I've added the description of both `el` and `e`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the plain javascript I used. Hope it helps you.

```
document.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e){
        var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    }else{
        var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    }
    if (key == '13') {
        //Code you would like to execute
    }
}
```

Comment: Use only `var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;`

Answer (score 0):

Rather, I'd suggest not to embed JavaScript in HTML.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
    var ele = document.getElementById('userInput');
    alert(ele.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="inputForm" >
  <label for="userInput">datt1939 : </label>
  <span id="userInputSpan">
    <input type="text" id="userInput">
  </span>
</form>
```

Since StackOverflow sandbox prevents `alert` from firing, here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxLmnsck/).

Comment: I like the approach, but it does not seem to work :/

Comment: @gkmohit It does work. StackOverflow prevents the `alert` from firing, maybe for security concerns.

Comment: do you think you could add jsfiddle ? :) it would make it easier :o

Comment: @gkmohit It'll not work if you include the script in `<head>`, use `DOMContentLoaded` or move the script to the end of `<body>`.

Comment: I understand what you have done now :), but what if I dont want a response when just enter is pressed  ? :) that is where your response is a little out of topic :)

Comment: @Leo The event should be added on `#userInput`, not on whole `document`.

Comment: @Tushar, I have the script in an external file :)

Comment: @gkmohit You are wrapping the `input` within a `form`. So that's the browser's default behavior, submit the form, when you press enter on an input field. If you don't want it, you could either remove the `form` wrapper, or listen to form's `submit` event and `return false` in the listener.

Comment: OR `event.preventDefault();` in the handler.

Comment: @Tushar yep, `preventDefault()`, instead of `return false`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways it can be done

Inline Event

```
<input type="text" value="" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) alert('Inline Event');" size="20" id="demo1" placeholder="Inline Event">
```

Unobtrusive Code using addEventListener

```
<input type="text" id="demo2" value="" size="20" placeholder="Using addEventListener">
```

Unobtrusive Code Calling a function

```
<input type="text" id="demo3" value="" onKeyUp="executeEvent(this,value)" size="20" placeholder="Seperate Handler">
```

JS

Attaching addEventListener to the DOM element

```
document.getElementById('demo2').addEventListener('keydown',function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('5');
    }
})
```

executeEvent function

```
function executeEvent(elem,value){
 console.log(elem)
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('You entered ' +elem.value);
    }
}
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4p0dpd7n/1/)