# Determine if a Letter or a number was pressed - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress, keydown

So I know that we can find if a key was pressed, and we can know which key was pressed by using javascript.

To determine if a key was down or pressed we can just use jQuery

```
$( "#some id" ).keydown(function()
```

or

```
$( "#m" ).keypress(function()
```

But this does not work pretty good for me.
I am trying to determine if a letter, or a number were pressed.

BUT, to be efficient, I don't want to check with a big if (or a for loop, worse) whether the key pressed was a letter or a character(by comparing and checking the character code)

Is there like a built in javascript function that determines if a number was pressed or a letter was pressed? is there an efficient way of doing this? or I am just overcomplicating things?

Comment: Yup, pretty sure peopel have done this before.

Comment: Check by ranges... Letters are all next to each other. So are numbers. You only need a couple if clauses

Comment: you could just check which range of codes are numbers and which are letters. I think numbers range from 48-57 and letters from 65-90 and num pad keys from 96-105

Comment: According to these answers you have to map the keyboard : http://stackoverflow.com/a/302161/3531064 http://stackoverflow.com/a/979686/3531064

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I would not agree. I know how to determine which key was pressed. I was looking specifically if there was a faster/cleaner way of determining a number or letter each time I would type.

Comment: @KevinCohen good thing SO is a democracy, it will be voted on. We will see ;)

Comment: It depends on your definition and your purpose -- ultimately, you might want to see what the character's [Unicode General Category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) is. Everything else is just making assumptions like "surely you can't type ä on a keyboard".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply check the range:

```
if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
    // Number
} else if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
    // Alphabet upper case
} else if (event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122) {
    // Alphabet lower case
}
```

Here is a detailed [answer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html) to a similar question. Good reference.

The Number pad code is the same as that above the keyboard: Reference from [Keyboard Keys and Key Code Values](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html)

---

### UPDATE:

Use the `.key`

```
var x = event.key; // instead of event.keyCode
```

and

```js
if (x >= 48 && x <= 57) {
    // Number
} else if (x >= 65 && x <= 90) {
    // Alphabet upper case
} else if (x >= 97 && x <= 122) {
    // Alphabet lower case
}
```

Comment: NP, @miqdadamirali got there a few seconds before me. Make sure you endorse his answer!

Comment: Ummm, what about capital letters? and num pad numbers?

Comment: I'll update the code

Comment: You are right @AdamBuchananSmith, although I implemented that myself, I just needed an idea and remembered that numbers and letters are grouped together

Comment: @KevinCohen so what is your point?! I can make the exact same argument about my answer then! LOL you are something else!

Comment: `isFinite(event.key)` to check if the key is a number. `event.key` contains the actual value, rather than a charCode

Comment: Numpad won't work.

Comment: Hello, e.keyCode is now deprecated.

Comment: Thank you @NoxFly, answer has been updated

Comment: As @Gibolt pointed out, ```event.key``` contains the actual value of the key, e.g. for "1" key it's 1 and not 49. Moreover, for letters ```event.key``` takes into account if Shift is pressed, so e.g. "M" key could be either "m" or "M". You can simply modify your answer by replacing charCodes by actual values (0-9, A-Z, a-z). For letters you'd need to check the ```x.length``` is 1 and it won't work for accented letters.