# Enter key press doesn't work for a login menu in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The problem is , when i hit enter key , it refreshes the page and put me into the same page , it doesnt even execute the `alerts`
I am using this javascript code to login by hitting enter key but it doesn't work .

```
 $("#btnLogin").keypress(function (e) {
        var code = e.which; 
        alert("stage 1");
        if (code == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();

                alert("stage 2");

        }

    });
```

i have used `keyup,keydown` also but they give me the same result, this is my html button

```
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="btnLogin">
                        Sign In</button>
```

Any help appreciated .

Comment: Do you include jQuery lib in your code? Cause it works on my side. You can check https://jsfiddle.net/hggo96ob/ , use tab to focus on the button and press enter.

Comment: Don't listen to the keypress event. Listen to the `submit` event of the respective form.

Comment: Are you executing `$("#btnLogin").keypress(` before the element has been created? For instance not executing it in a `$(document).ready` callback.

Comment: it is in  $(document).ready

Comment: im using jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: Try using `e.preventDefault()` at the top of the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved

i have used following code

```
 $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
           alert('You pressed enter!');

        }
    });
```

instead of using `LoginId` in used document  and then it worked .

I found the answer from the link below
[here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)

Thanks for your time you spend toanswer the question above

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your if statement you need to add `e.preventDefault()` in order for it not to submit your form (which is what the default for enter key in a form).