# If keycode && input are not empty do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I have barcode input in which I enter barcodes multiple times, every time I add barcode, barcode is added to the list even if I only press enter with empty value.

I want to start function only if user press enter `key == 13` and value is not empty.

This is code:

```
if(key == 13) {}
```

I tried but without success:

```
var value = $("#barcode").val();
if(key == 13 && value.length > 0)
{alert("This works!")}...
```

Comment: How and where do you declare and define `key`? What do you mean by “without success”? Is there an error message? Does it somehow ignore the length of the value?

Comment: How to detect pressing Enter on keyboard using jQuery? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your code under either the `keyup` or `keypress` event. Assuming you use jQuery to attach the event, you should also use the `which` property of the provided event object to get the keycode. Try this:

```
$('#barcode').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && this.value) {
        alert("This works!")
    }
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0qp4p9a2/)