# Jquery trigger on keypress call function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

my question is about :

i want to trigger this function on enter click

```
$('.s-link').click(function()
{
    var x = "/search/node?keys=";
    var y = $('.i-search').val();
    var result = x + y;
    $('a').attr('href', result);

});
```

Comment: Provide us with your html element as well.

Comment: <li class="search-share">
    <a class="link s-link">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </a>
    <span class="share-search-block"><input id="myInput" type="search" class="i-search" placeholder="Search ..."></span>
  </li>

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, please. Edit your question and paste relevant information there. Thanks. Also, jQuery has https://api.jquery.com/keydown/. `click` is for mouse clicks, not key clicks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect pressing Enter on keyboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can put code inside onclick

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {
    alert('You pressed enter!');
    var x = "/search/node?keys=";
var y = $('.i-search').val();
var result = x + y;
$('a').attr('href', result);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#someTextBox').keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
       var x = "/search/node?keys=";
       var y = $('.i-search').val();
       var result = x + y;
      $('a').attr('href', result);

    }
});
```

try  this and change #someTextBox according to your program