# How can I trigger button click on key press?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Suppose I have the following 3 buttons:

```html
<div role="button" class="ico-btn">
  Button A
</div>
<div role="button" class="ico-btn">
  Button B
</div>
<div role="button" class="ico-btn">
  Button C
</div>
```

Is there any way to trigger `Button A` by pressing the <kbd>A</kbd> key on the keyboard, or `Button B` by pressing the <kbd>B</kbd> key on the keyboard, etc.? Something like an attribute keypress="A" to make things more accessible?

Comment: something like this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery

Comment: The duplicate has your answer. It's regarding listening for the Return key, but the pattern is the same. Hook the event handler and interrogate the event to determine what key was pressed.

Comment: @Vibs not everything requires jQuery.

Comment: @Olian04 Where did he say it did? The OP has tagged it so I don't see his suggestion as unreasonable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my bad. I missed that the question was tagged with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easily with delegated event listeners:

```js
// listen for keys
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){

    // all divs with the attribute data-listening_key
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-listening_key]');
    elems.forEach(function(element, index){

        // if the one it's listening for matches this event
        var listening_key = element.dataset.listening_key;
        if(listening_key === event.key){
            var clickEvent = new Event('click'); // create and dispatch a click to it!
            element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div data-listening_key='x' onclick="console.log('Button A clicked')">
    Button A
</div>
<div data-listening_key='y' onclick="console.log('Button B clicked')">
    Button B
</div>
<div data-listening_key='z' onclick="console.log('Button C clicked')">
    Button C
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `addEventListener` to document and check `keyCode`. For `A` it is 65

```js
document.getElementById('btnA').addEventListener('click', triggerA)

// function which will trigger on click of A
// So dirctly clicking A this function will trigger. 
// This is just for validation
function triggerA() {
  console.log('A')
}

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 65) {
    // on press of A the div#btnA is getting clicked
    document.getElementById('btnA').click();
  }
})
```

```css
.ico-btn {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div role="button" class="ico-btn" id='btnA'>
  Button A
</div>
<div role="button" class="ico-btn">
  Button B
</div>
<div role="button" class="ico-btn">
  Button C
</div>
```