How to get input value in keypress enter
I have a textbox for search items. I want to get items when type text in textbox and press enter key.
<input id="txt-search" placeholder="@StoreResource.SearchHere" class="form-control main-in">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn-search" class="search-icon">
        <i class="icon feather icon-search"></i>
    </a>

I use this code but get empty value.
$("#txt-search").keyup(function (e) {
     var txt = $(this).val();

     if (e.key == "Enter") {
         alert(txt);
     }
})


this question was answered already. check the reference link below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-can-i-detect-pressing-enter-on-the-keyboard-using-jquery
this might help you.

try e.keyCode == 13?

keyup occurs before the value has been updated.  Use $("#txt-search").on("input", function().. then debounce and run your code as the user types instead of only on enter



$("#txt-search").keypress(function (e) {
   if (e.which == 13) { // 13 is the Enter key
      var txt = $(this).val();
      alert(txt);
      $(this).val('');
    }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt-search" placeholder="@StoreResource.SearchHere" class="form-control main-in">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn-search" class="search-icon">
        <i class="icon feather icon-search"></i>
    </a>



This code works as expected. When entering the value into the text box and press enter then get the value which is entered into the textbox.

Thanks it is ok , but when show alert, empty textbox

@ar.gorgin, I have updated the code. When you enter the value into the textbox and press enter it will show alert first and then empty the textbox.

No, when show alert Its value will be empty. The value should not be empty

@ar.gorgin, Can you please clarify what you want from the code?
