# How can I convert a char to its keycode?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert a character to its respective keycode?

For example:

- `a` to `65`
- `b` to `66`
- `c` to `67`
- `d` to `68`

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Comment: see [FULL list of JavaScript keycodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603195/full-list-of-javascript-keycodes)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/charCodeAt) function to achieve this.

Working example:

```js
function showKeyCode () {
    var character = document.getElementById("character").value.substring(0, 1);
    var code = document.getElementById("character").value.charCodeAt(0);
    var msg = "The Key Code for the \"" + character + "\" character is " + code + ".";
    alert(msg);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="character" size="15">
<input type="button" value="Show Key Code" onclick="showKeyCode();">
```

Comment: i'm having a char let say 'a' and i need to find the respective keycode of 'a'.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this really answers the question - it depends what you mean by "keycode". This function gives you the character code, not the key code, which may not be the same thing.

Comment: Either the term keycode MUST be changed in the original question, or this is a wrong answer. Keycode is what you get from e.which - when a key is pressed.

Comment: Something is wrong.... when I press "." (the point) on my keyboard my event.KeyCode = 190.... If I do your code the ".".charCodeAt(0) = 46... why?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it's currently worded. If you're actually looking to convert ASCII characters to keycodes, see Tim's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1432067/78639

Comment: This is not the correct/authoritative answer for the question, the solution provided does not return the keycode for the character pressed on the keyboard. There are several references here that point to that.

Comment: some of code will work, others dont ...
http://jsbin.com/rovogiqucu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: `charCodeAt` doesn't work for `'a'`, it gives 97 but the keycode is 65

Answer (score 14):

What do you mean by "keyCode"? Different browsers have different `keyCode` values in `keyup` and `keydown` events which will not necessarily correspond to the ASCII code for the corresponding character. For alphanumeric keys, the `keypress` event will give you the ASCII code in most browsers via the `charCode` or `which` properties. [This page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) is useful.

**Update September 2015**

As pointed out by Jan in the comments, `keyCode` will eventually be superseded by the superior [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property. However, there is not much browser support for this yet.

Comment: @Jan: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), `char` has been dropped. `key` is much better than `keyCode` but is not yet widely supported. For the short-to-medium term, `keyCode` and `which` are staying with us.

Comment: Nice. Yours should be the accepted answer by the way. The accepted answer doesn't answer the question at all. It answers a *different* question, but not the asked one

Comment: "the superior key property"?!? I don't see how working with strings like `"ArrowDown"` or `"Enter"` is supposed to be better than working with ASCII Integer values or how deprecating both `keyCode` and `which` is supposed to be helpful to anyone. Without at least a practical, standard way to convert `"Enter"` to `13` and back, this makes no sense whatsoever!

Comment: As of 2021, `key` does seem to have [decent support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 10):

Here is a object with some keys and their corresponding keycodes:

```
{"0":48,"1":49,"2":50,"3":51,"4":52,"5":53,"6":54,"7":55,"8":56,"9":57,"d":68,"b":66,"a":65,"s":83,"i":73,"f":70,"k":75,"ß":219,"Dead":220,"+":187,"ü":186,"p":80,"o":79,"u":85,"z":90,"t":84,"r":82,"e":69,"w":87,"g":71,"h":72,"j":74,"l":76,"ö":192,"ä":222,"#":191,"y":89,"x":88,"c":67,"v":86,"n":78,"m":77,",":188,".":190,"-":189,"ArrowRight":39,"ArrowLeft":37,"ArrowUp":38,"ArrowDown":40,"PageDown":34,"Clear":12,"Home":36,"PageUp":33,"End":35,"Delete":46,"Insert":45,"Control":17,"AltGraph":18,"Meta":92,"Alt":18,"Shift":16,"CapsLock":20,"Tab":9,"Escape":27,"F1":112,"F2":113,";":188,":":190,"_":189,"'":191,"*":187,"Q":81,"W":87,"E":69,"R":82,"T":84,"Z":90,"S":83,"A":65,"D":68,"I":73,"U":85,"O":79,"Y":89,"X":88,"C":67,"F":70,"V":86,"G":71,"B":66,"H":72,"N":78,"J":74,"M":77,"K":75,"L":76,"P":80,"Ö":192,"Ä":222,"Ü":186,"!":49,"\"":50,"§":51,"$":52,"%":53,"&":54,"/":55,"(":56,")":57,"=":48,"?":219,"°":220}
```

if some keys are missing or are different for your browser, you can use the following function:

```
let a = {}
document.addEventListener("keydown", ({key, keyCode}) => a[key] = keyCode);
```

Just copy it to the console and smash your head on the keyboard. The result will be stored in `a`

Comment: What browser(s) is that list valid for?

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments: the **accepted answer is not correct**, because it gives the character code and not the keyCode, which can be different, e.g. `'a'.charCodeAt(0) == 97` while the correct keyCode is `65`.

for converting just the **standard characters from [a-zA-Z] or numbers [0-9]** the code below can be used.

However this **does not work correctly for any special keys** like `.`, `Ö`, `#` or whatsoever and I did not find a good solution for them. As a workaround one could use a site like http://keycode.info/ (which just captures the `onkeydown` events and reads the `event.keyCode` property).

```js
function convertToKeyCode(target) {
    var keyCode = target.value.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
    document.getElementById("keyCodeSpan").innerHTML = keyCode;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="convertToKeyCode(this)" size="1" maxlength="1">
<span>Keycode: </span><span id="keyCodeSpan"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Find a keycode/ASCII chart like [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20110807175224/http://www.meelink.com/webboard/data/3/0097-1.html) and put it into an array such that array['char'] = keycode.  This is tedious, but the code will execute pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this when I stumbled upon this question. I do not think the marked answer is the right answer. For simple letters, A-Za-z, I use the following:

```
function getKeyCode(char) {
  var keyCode = char.charCodeAt(0);
  if(keyCode > 90) {  // 90 is keyCode for 'z'
    return keyCode - 32;
  }
  return keyCode;
}
```

Please note that this is meant to work for characters A-Z and a-z only.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```js
let character = prompt('input a character');

console.log(character.charCodeAt(0));
```

For a basic concept, you should use the method 'string.charCodeAt(0)'.

For example, in JavaScript, 'A'.charCodeAt(0).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).