# keycode on keydown event

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I'm using `keydown` event

Where I get the keycode and convert it to charcode.

But I got a problem where in keyboard is press `2` it gives `50` and charcode as `2`

When I press `2` in numpad it gives keycode `98`, so when I convert charcode `a`

Answer (score 13):

That is happening because you are using the `keyCode` member, for example, a lower case 'a' and an upper case 'A' have the same keyCode, because is the same key, but a different charCode because the resulting character is different.

To get the charCode, you should use the `keypress` event, and get the `event.charCode` member if available, otherwise, you get the `event.keyCode` which for IE, on the keypress event has the right information.

Give a look to the following [example](http://jsbin.com/ahizi):

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) { 
  e = e || window.event; 
  var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode, 
      character = String.fromCharCode(charCode); 

  alert(character);
};
```

Comment: with this code:
when I type "2" i get charCode 0; keyCode 50; character 2;
when I type Shift-2 I get the same, but in my textbox the "@" appears.

onkeypress event doesn't seem to know whether yoour Shift key is down....

Answer (score 2):

just look at these solution [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430989/how-to-convert-char-to-keycode) to your requirement

and for keycode reference [use this](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx)

and keycode is depend on browser [check it](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Answer (score 1):

you'll get character code in `keypress` event
try this out: http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html

They use following code to convert to character:

```
var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : evt.keyCode;
```

[this](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) also may be helpful as keycodes reference