# Using Javascript to Auto move cursor onto next form field

Tags: javascript

Is it possible using `Javascipt` to automatically send the user from one field to the next when the `maxlength` of the field has been reached?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible. Suppose your textbox max length is 5. You need to make an function onkeyup event and count the length of the textbox value. In this function if length is equal or exceed to 5 then you need to write second textbox focus function calls.

Comment: i used this code:
function moveOnMax(field,nextFieldID)
 {
    if(field.value.length >= field.maxLength)
  {
      document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
    }
 }
 <input name="productkey1"  type="text" id="productkey"  onKeyUp="moveOnMax(this,productkey2)" size="4" maxlength="5"/> 
    - <input name="productkey2"  type="text" id="productkey2" size="4" maxlength="5"/> 
but its not working

Comment: @user2156244 : Use this Corrected code.... <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function moveOnMax(field, nextFieldID) { if (field.value.length >= field.maxLength) { nextFieldID.focus(); } }
        </script>
        <input name="productkey1" type="text" id="productkey" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,document.getElementById('productkey2'))"
            size="4" maxlength="5" />
        <input name="productkey2" type="text" id="productkey2" size="4" maxlength="5" />

Comment: /*← and →*/
var keyUpTimeout;
        $body.on('keyup', '.auto-focus-prev-next', function (event) {
            var $target = $(event.target);
            clearTimeout(keyUpTimeout);
            keyUpTimeout= setTimeout(function() {
                if ($target.val().length === parseInt($target.attr('maxlength'))) {
                    $target.nextAll('input:not([readonly]):first').focus();
                }
                if($target.val().length === 0) {
                    $target.prevAll('input:not([readonly]):first').focus();
                }
            }, 100);
        });

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#productkey1').keyup(function() {
     if(this.value.length >= $(this).attr('maxlength'))
     {
         $('#productkey2').next().focus();
     }
 });
```

Comment: in case the user copies a large amount of contents into the textbox, it is better to use `>=` instead of `==`

Comment: try by removing .next().can u show me the code

Comment: Code:
`<script>
$('#productkey1').keyup(function() {

     if(this.value.length == $(this).attr('maxlength'))

     {

         $('#productkey2').focus();

     }

 });

</script>

    <input name="productkey1"  type="text" id="productkey1"  size="4" maxlength="5"/> 


    - <input name="productkey2"  type="text" id="productkey2" size="4" maxlength="5"/>`

Comment: @user2156244 i created link http://jsfiddle.net/khbEL/ see here it is working

Comment: is it working now for u

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would need to:

- monitor the [`onkeydown`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648130/keycode-on-keydown-event) event to prevent the characters from 'overflowing',
- look up the next input field in your form - based on your own logic/structure - when such happens,
- use the [`focus`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543967/setting-focus-to-a-textbox-when-a-function-is-called) method to set the focus on it that next field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to calculate the number of charecter inserted in the field by `onkeyup` event and if the number is equal to maxlength then set the `focus` to next field

Comment: i used this function:
    `function moveOnMax(field,nextFieldID)
 {
    if(field.value.length >= field.maxLength)
  {
      document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
    }
 }`
But its not working

Comment: you should make the `field` as object before finding the length. So before passing it into if clasue, create an object saying `document.getElementById(field)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use code like this using jquery. In this code it will move to #second field when text is larger then 20 characters

```
<input id="first"/>
<input id="second"/>
<script>
$(function() {
   $('#first').keypress(function() {
      var self = $(this);
      //wait until character is inserted
      setTimeout(function() {
         if (self.val().length > 20) {
            $('#second').focus();
         }
      }, 1);
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: why are you using the setTimeout?

Comment: @SwissCoder sorry I have no idea, it was created 9 years ago. Maybe it was not working without it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to hook into the `onfocus` event for the input to know you are starting the measuring. Then you need to check the length of the entered characters with the `onkeyup` event. Once your limit is reached you can call `focus()` on the next DOM element you want to move the cursor to. You will also need to use the `onblur` event to know that you have stopped measuring the length of an input.

For example, using jQuery;

```
<input id="inputA" type="text"/>
<input id="inputB" type="text"/>

<script>

var $input;

$('#inputA').focus(function() {
    $input = $(this);
});

$(window).keyup(function() {
    if($input && $input.val().length == 5) {
        $('#inputB').focus();
    }
});

$('#inputA').blur(function() {
    $input = null;
});

</script>
```