# What are the JavaScript KeyCodes?

Tags: javascript, keycode

What keycodes are available for JavaScript? If they're not the same for all browsers, please list the keycodes for each browser.

Comment: So for complete you want like the whole unicode range? You should specify what do you mean by "complete".

Comment: By complete I mean containing all keycode numbers. The examples I gave give the numbers 8,9,13,16,17... Thus skipping some numbers.

Comment: I do believe that there are a countable number of characters for which JavaScript keycodes are assigned.

Comment: Why not create such a table yourself using JavaScript?

Comment: @pimvdb Took your advice! http://stackoverflow.com/a/14905611/552067

Comment: @pimvdb watch out, different browsers give different key codes in JavaScript. If you try it in JavaScript be sure to check FireFox and non-FireFox, and be especially wary for key codes 59 61 173 186 187 189.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Followed [@pimvdb's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603195/full-list-of-javascript-keycodes#comment6380666_5603195), and created my own:

http://daniel-hug.github.io/characters/

Be patient, as it takes a few seconds to generate an element for each of the 65536 characters that have a JavaScript keycode.

Comment: Horrible site, lets my browser crash everytime. Dont use this!

Comment: @Floeee Sorry, it currently generates a table row for all 65536 characters that have a javascript keycode. It does this very efficiently, but it still takes 10-20 seconds. I might change it so it loads 1000 just to start, then more upon request. Answer edited to explain this.

Comment: Why don't you display a simple text message at the start of the page explaining this?

Comment: It may be more accurate to say "it takes 10-20 seconds to irreversibly crash your browser until you terminate the process."

Comment: Okay, got around the loading and crashing. BUT....it doesnt work. Atleast not with delete or backspace. Have you thought about not loading them all at once, but rather catch the event, dynamically post it to a php that pulls it out of the db and then displays the results? This is a really cool idea. Clean it up. Chances are, noone will be going there to grab anything other than a few keycodes.

Alternative for nonSQL user approach....put all the results in a php page and use ajax/jquery to send the user input and pull the results. Then you dont have to have a loading issue on arrival.

Comment: I looked at the code and I don't believe it's right to say it does it *very efficiently*. However, in lieu of myself not having a replacement solution... carry on.

Comment: These are charCodes not keyCodes.
keyCodes are listed under 3.3 section of http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: These are Unicode charCodes. For JavaScript keyboardEvent keyCodes, use [@Nimphious's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12476699/3471286) script. It is not complete for non-US keyboards though, be aware.

Comment: Yeah..., it crashed my browser too..

Answer (score 59):

keyCodes are *different* from the ASCII values. For a complete keyCode reference, see http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

For example, Numpad numbers have keyCodes 96 - 105, which corresponds to the beginning of lowercase alphabet in ASCII. This could lead to problems in validating numeric input.

Comment: The page linked to does not contain a complete reference. It adequately explains that the keycodes depend on the keyboard and the meanings of keycodes or keycode combinations depend on software that interprets them. So there can be no full list.

Comment: [http://www.javascriptkeycode.com](http://www.javascriptkeycode.com) has a handy key code generator I've used recently to test different keyboard combinations.

Answer (score 19):

I needed something like this for a game's control configuration UI, so I compiled a list for the standard US keyboard layout keycodes and mapped them to their respective key names.

Here's a fiddle that contains a map for code -> name and visi versa: http://jsfiddle.net/vWx8V/

If you want to support other key layouts you'll need to modify these maps to accommodate for them separately.

That is unless you were looking for a list of keycode values that included the control characters and other special values that are not (or are rarely) possible to input using a keyboard and may be outside of the scope of the `keydown`/`keypress`/`keyup` events of Javascript. Many of them are control characters or special characters like `null` (`\0`) and you most likely won't need them.

Notice that the number of keys on a full keyboard is less than many of the keycode values.

Comment: one more note of thanks. having these already in objects is a nice time saver.

Comment: When I press the right+cmd button on my mac it returns Right Click?

Answer (score 8):

http://keycodes.atjayjo.com/

This app is just awesome. It is essentially a virtual keyboard that immediately shows you the keycode pressed on a standard US keyboard.

Comment: Despite the OP's effort to follow up. This *is* just awesome!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete list--I believe: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: I created a gist with a KEY_CODE constant based on this link: https://gist.github.com/DJDaveMark/eb9725825ac3a87616c66d05a8cf8f4a

Answer (score 3):

Here are some useful links:

- http://www.toolcase.org/charset.php?charset=UTF-8&min=0&per=512&search=

The 2nd column is the keyCode and the html column shows how it will displayed.
You can test it [here](http://jsbin.com/eruwoh/4/edit).

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer will be given when you run this snippet.

```js
document.write('<table>')
for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
  document.write('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + String.fromCharCode(i) + '</td></tr>')
}
document.write('</table>')
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 1px 12px;
  text-align: right;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
* {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Comment: These aren't keycodes, they're character codes. That's different