# javascript keycodes reference

Tags: javascript, keycode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FULL list of JavaScript keycodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603195/full-list-of-javascript-keycodes)

Where can I found the **official** reference of the key codes in javascript?

Google founds only gappy tables.

Especially I'm looking for the key code of double quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're testing for typed characters (as opposed to detecting non-printable keystrokes) then you do not need a look-up table. Use the `keypress` event and you can get the character code and hence typed character from the event in any major browser:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof evt.which == "number") ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (String.fromCharCode(charCode) == '"') {
        alert("Double quote typed");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Personnally I use this list : http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes
And this is kind of a reference for JS keyboard events : http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 0):

Key code for `doube quote` is <strike>34</strike> 222 (Mozzila, firefox, IE) similar question is already asked here: [What are the JavaScript KeyCodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603195/full-list-of-javascript-keycodes)

Comment: just updated i think its 222

Comment: 34 was ok, the event, what I have used was not