# Keydown keycode not returning expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I am a bit confused by the character codes returned by the keyCode property on the keydown event.
I was expecting the codes to align with the ascii codes. A lot of them seem to do, but I am getting unexpected results for some: Examples are the delete keys and the '.' key

Using the bellow code: I get the following codes back:
DeleteKey: 46 (ASCII val = 127)

DelKey:110

'.' : 190 - which isn't even in the default ascii table.

It seems like the delete key maps to the Ascii code for the '.' key

I am using IE 9 to do the testing.

Is it a misunderstanding on my part that these are supposed to map to the decimal entries in the ascii table?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").live("keydown", function (e) {
            console.log(e.keyCode);
        });
    });


</script>

<div id="parent">
<span id="target">Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `e.which` to get the keycode - http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5871443/778118)... As it states, keycodes and ASCII values are **NOT** the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that keyCode and ASCII are the same.

To get the value of the keyCode, you can use

```
$("body").live("keydown",function(e){
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this for display purposes, but I have to act on the keyCodes in some cases. I will look at the mapped values in the link provided by @jahroy