# Convert from characters to KeyCode

Tags: javascript, char, keycode

I everyone,
I must convert a character to keyCode... I must not convert to charCode...

For example if I have a "." (a dot) I need to obtain "190" as result.. but If I do

```
".".charCodeAt(0)
```

I obtain "46"... "46" is not the result I want... 
I have also tried to do

```
String.fromCharCode(190);
```

In this case I do not obtain "." but I obtain "3/4".

How can I convert the character to obtain "190"?

**UPDATE** 
I must compare the input from the keyboard with a value in a "string"... I need to do something like this

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == ".") <-- I need to get the keyCode of the "."
    {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

That is an example.... I do not know which is the char I could need to compare... It could be a ".", or a ",", o something else...

Thank you all.

Comment: I updated my question... however if I press the "." on the keyboard I can see the "." has the code 190... see the answer of @Torean

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking and you reminded me of something simelar I needed to do. what you can do is maybe use a eventListener and log the code to the console. for example:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

This will just log out the keycode of every pressed key on the keyboard

here is the link to the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/09798khL/

Comment: the character I need to get te code does not come from keyboard :(

Comment: What input device are you using?

Answer (score 0):

While I do not have a solution for converting special characters to keyCodes (also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49897083/9219743 ), here another solution for your problem - just use:

`if(e.key == '.') {//do something}`

So compare to `e.key` (which is the actual character) instead of `e.keyCode`.