# charCodeAt generates wrong code for comma

Tags: javascript

Why does code:

```
','.charCodeAt(0);
```

generates `44` even though charcode for comma is `188` (both by [this table](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) and when getting `event.keyCode` in `keyup` handler).

Comment: `charCodeAt()` returns the ascii value of the character. `44` is the ascii code of a comma. See http://www.asciitable.com/ for more.

Comment: Characters and keys are two different things. That's why they don't necessarily have the same code.

Comment: I understand the confusion, especially when SO has questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430989/how-to-convert-char-to-keycode where the accepted answer confuses the two terms and other answers contain outdated information. These should ideally be cleaned up.

Comment: @gre_gor please make this an answer.

Comment: I'm feeling a bit silly right now. Thanks for answers (if any of you would make actual answer out of your comments I would gladly officially accept it). Seems like I would have to "convert" keycodes to chars some other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters and keys are different things.

[`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) returns the numeric Unicode value of the character.
`keyCode` from the [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) represents a key on a keyboard.

Since there is no 1:1 mapping between characters and keys, they don't necessarily use the same values.

Comment: And if you absoutely *have* to map keycodes to charcodes you could do so through an array. You would have to write that implementation yourself though, it's not built-in.