# How To Simulate Pressing Special Keys In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm trying to simulate user keyboard input and have read through the answers for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430989/how-to-convert-a-char-to-its-keycode), but the answer(s) don't work for special keys such as `$`.  For example, when I try to simulate pressing `$` with

```
let data = {
    code: "Digit4",
    key: "$",
    keyCode: 52,
    shiftKey: true
};
let key_event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", data);
myElement.dispatchEvent(key_event);
```

4 gets pressed/printed, not `$`.

If I change keypress to keydown or keyup, then nothing happens. What is the correct way to simulate the user pressing a special key like $ then? Also, I'm on Mac/Chrome if it matters

Comment: Can you achieve the desired result by using the input event instead of the keypress event?

Comment: @Amila Unfortunately I can't, I'm dealing with a canvas element and the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) doesn't have support for canvas elements

Comment: Logging a native `keypress` event when `$` gets entered (so when shift and 4 are pressed), gives me a `keyCode: 36`, why is it `52` in your code?

Comment: @CBroe using [this tool](https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode), it shows `$` as having a keyCode of `52`, and that `Home` has a keyCode of `36`. However, I just tried it again with also specifying `code`, `key` and `shiftKey`, and `$` gets pressed! Thank you for  solving my question!