# form default button not working in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox

Hi I've created a simple form with a link button. In my page load I set default button to that linkbutton as

this.Form.DefaultButton = this.btnSearch.UniqueID;

it is working fine in IE but not in Firefox.

Anyone has solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a Panel control within form and put all controls which are on form within panel. It should work.

**UPDATE**
Use JQuery
And add this [Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817540/clicking-a-link-when-enter-key-is-pressed-using-jquery/1817655#1817655)

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick response. I tried like this but not working (I've a master page)