# How Do I Prevent Enter Key Submit in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, submit, keypress, forms

I'd like to either simply swallow an *Enter* key press in `<input>` fields or else instead substitute *Tab* key presses.  I haven't yet decided which is best.

How can I do this in jQuery?  I've got this so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    //handle enter key
    $("input").keypress(function (e) {
        var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (k == 13) {
            //???
        }
    });
});
```

(That `e.keyCode || e.which` part was recommended in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed/302161#302161).)

What might I put there to either (a) cancel the event or else to (b) force a Tab key press?

Answer (score 15):

With e.preventDefault() you can prevent the default action, which in this case is submiting the form.

Answer (score 8):

Or `return false;`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...
  //handle enter key
  $("input").keypress(function (e) {
      var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if (k == 13) {
          return false; // !!!
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you'd like to just mimic a tab to the next control, as you mentioned, you could try [this method by jdsharp](http://jqueryminute.com/set-focus-to-the-next-input-field-with-jquery/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
//handle enter key
$("input").keypress(function (e) {
    var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (k == 13) {
            $(this).focusNextInputField();
        }
    });
});
```