# How to REALLY limit the available character for an input field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dom-events

I just started adding JS-validation to a signup form and I want the username input field in a Twitter-style (using jQuery). That means that the input is limited to certain characters and other characters do not even appear.

So far, I've got this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('input#user_login').keyup(function() { 
    jQuery(this).val( jQuery(this).val().replace(/[^a-z0-9\_]+/i, '') );
  });
});
```

This solution works, but the problem is that the illegal character appears as long as the user hasn't released the key (please excuse my terrible English!) and the `keyup` event isn't triggered. The character flickers in the input field for a second and then disappears.

The ideal solution would be the way Twitter does it: The character doesn't even show up once.

How can I do that? I guess I'll have to intercept the input in some way.

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ tried that?

Comment: Please note, that the user could still manipulate the code and send whatever they want, so server-side security and checkups are also needed.

Comment: of course! This is only for the users' comfort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to limit the characters the user may type rather than the particular keys that will be handled, you have to use `keypress`, as that's the only event that reports character information rather than key codes. Here is a solution that limits characters to just A-Z letters in all mainstream browsers (without using jQuery):

```
<input type="text" id="alpha">


<script type="text/javascript">

function alphaFilterKeypress(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    return /[a-z]/i.test(charStr);
}

window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("alpha");
    input.onkeypress = alphaFilterKeypress;
};

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that whas it, I modified your code a little, check out my response.

Answer (score 3):

Try using keydown instead of keyup

```
jQuery('input#user_login').keydown(function() {
```

Aside: You selector is slower than it needs to be. ID is unique, and fastest, so

```
jQuery('#user_login').keydown(function() {
```

Should suffice

You might want to consider capturing the keycode iself, before assigning it to the val

```
if (event.keyCode == ...)
```

Also, are you considering the alt, ctls, and shift keys?

```
if (event.shiftKey) {

if (event.ctrlKey) {

if (event.altKey) {
```

Comment: Using keydown doesn't work. It looks like the input hasn't arrived in the jQuery('input').var() method and the illegal input is only replaced after a SECOND keystroke. So in a way it doesn't work.

Comment: So, just to confirm, keyup, keydown, and keypress do not work?

Comment: Edited further - have you considered capturing event.keycode?

Comment: Yap. But the strange thing is: On keydown the character disappears immediately. The only problem here is, that this only happens after I enter a second character. So I enter "-" and it stays where it is, that I enter "a" and the "-" disappears. Could this have something to do with my regular expression? Keypress doesn't work in some browsers and doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: My mistake, I read about it on stackoverflow... ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed )

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @TimDown that solved the issue! I modified your code a little so it accepts backspace and arrows for editing (I post a reply to use code formatting).

Thank you very much.

```
function alphaFilterKeypress(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;

    // START CHANGE: Allow backspace and arrows
    if(/^(8|37|39)$/i.test(evt.keyCode)) { return; }
    // END CHANGE

    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    // I also changed the regex a little to accept alphanumeric characters + '_'
    return /[a-z0-9_]/i.test(charStr);
}

window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("user_login");
    input.onkeypress = alphaFilterKeypress;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the *maxlength* property in inputs and passwords: [info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) (that's actually the way Twitter does it).

Comment: "That means that the input is limited to certain characters and other characters do not even appear." I think it is, why go the complicated JS route when it can be done much easier and faster with plain html?

Comment: nope. I'm well aware of the maxlength property. I wanted to prevent CERTAIN characters from appearing in the input field (!"§/$&)