# why my code that write by me is upper,when keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#a').keyup(
  function(event){
   alert(event.keyValue)
  }
)
```

but error,coz 'keyValue' is not undefined,

how do i get the keyValue when the event keyup???

i use jquery.

thanks

---

i do this:

```
$('#a').keyup(
  function(event){
   alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which))
  }
```

but it alert the value of upper

ex:

i   alert  I

l   alert L

why???
    )

Comment: You mean it's changing the case on you? That definitely shouldn't be happening and has never happened to me in either FF3.5, IE6-7-8, Safari or Chrome using jQuery 1.4.1. What browser are you using? What version of jQuery?

Comment: my browser  is firefox ,and i test it in chrome ,it  is the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `event.keyCode` instead

Answer (score 1):

JQuery places the key pressed into `event.which` across all browsers.

See here: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

> To determine which key was pressed, we
>   can examine the event object that is
>   passed to the handler function. While
>   browsers use differing attributes to
>   store this information, jQuery
>   normalizes the .which attribute so we
>   can reliably use it to retrieve the
>   key code

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question:  [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)