# Execute function by pressing "return" using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two text inputs like the following, i don't want to use `<form>` , so i want when people press "return" BUTTON after filling the inputs, a function called "doit()" should be executed.

```
<script>
function doit(){
alert("you submitted the info");
..........ajax code........
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="text" id="skills" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do what you are looking for.

```
$('#emails, #skills').keypress(function(e){
   if( e.keyCode == $.keyCode.ENTER || e.keyCode == $.keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER ){
     yourSubroutine();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#name, #last').bind('keydown', function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 108) {
                        doit();
                    }
                });
```

[KeyCode can be found here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/JqueryUtils)

Comment: I mean the RETURN button in keyboard

Comment: what do u mean bu the return button?? backspace?

Comment: RETURN should either be ENTER (13) or NUMPAD_ENTER (108)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed). Essentially, you'll want to bind a keypress listener, and then check for the return key.