# Trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event in JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

What is the best way to simulate a user entering text in a text input box in JS and/or jQuery?

I **don't** want to actually put text in the input box, I just want to trigger all the event **handlers** that would normally get triggered by a user typing info into a input box. This means focus, keydown, keypress, keyup, and blur. I think.

So how would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

You can trigger any of the events with a direct call to them, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('item').keydown();
    $('item').keypress();
    $('item').keyup();
    $('item').blur();
});
```

Does that do what you're trying to do?

You should probably also trigger `.focus()` and potentially `.change()`

If you want to trigger the key-events with specific keys, you can do so like this:

```
$(function() {
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 65; // Character 'A'
    $('item').trigger(e);
});
```

There is some interesting discussion of the keypress events here: [jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed), specifically regarding cross-browser compatability with the .which property.

Comment: or `$('item').trigger('keypress', {which: 'A'.charCodeAt(0)});`

Comment: @ebynum Can you write some code with Javascript (no jquery).

Comment: If you need Ctrl: `ctrlKey: true`, also: `shiftKey`, `altKey`

Comment: KeyboardEvent([typeArg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#events), [KeyboardEventInit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent))

Answer (score 116):

You could dispatching events using [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) and [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) like this:

```
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'}));
```

Comment: or `el.dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress', {keyCode: 'a'}))`

Comment: @Cuzox why not use KeyboardEvent? It autofills values like shiftKey and it is the correct way. Also, you put a string in keyCode, that is wrong.

Comment: If you need `Ctrl`: 
`el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { keyCode: 70, ctrlKey: true }));` (This will cause a shortcut `Ctrl + F`)

Comment: KeyboardEvent([typeArg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#events), [KeyboardEventInit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent))

Answer (score 35):

To trigger an <kbd>enter</kbd> keypress, I had to modify @ebynum response, specifically, using the keyCode property.

```
e = $.Event('keyup');
e.keyCode= 13; // enter
$('input').trigger(e);
```

Comment: `keydown` event isn't being caught, or am I doing something wrong here? fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/8d8J9

Comment: @cloak: it works. Check my comment here for a complete selector to fix asp.net controls: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/269388/How-prevent-Textbox-postback-when-hit-enter-key-in?msg=5145046#xx5145046xx Make sure you call it after you insert anything in the dom if using Ajax.

Comment: Warning: `keyCode `  property is deprecated; you should use KeyboardEvent.key instead, if available.

Answer (score 29):

You can achieve this with: `EventTarget.dispatchEvent(event)` and by passing in a new KeyboardEvent as the event.

For example: `element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key': 'a'}))`

Working example:

```js
// get the element in question
const input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

// focus on the input element
input.focus();

// add event listeners to the input element
input.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  console.log("You have pressed key: ", event.key);
});

input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  console.log(`key: ${event.key} has been pressed down`);
});

input.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  console.log(`key: ${event.key} has been released`);
});

// dispatch keyboard events
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',  {'key':'h'}));
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',  {'key':'e'}));
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'key':'y'}));
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="foo" />
```

[MDN dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

[MDN KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent)

Comment: the code snippet doesn't work on Chrome - do you know why..?

Comment: Hmn, for me it works in chrome, version `121.0.6167.161`

Answer (score 28):

Here's a vanilla js example to trigger any event:

```
function triggerEvent(el, type){
if ('createEvent' in document) {
        // modern browsers, IE9+
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
        // IE 8
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you furnish a few examples of usage? How would your function be used to send a keycode?

Comment: The source code for this post can be found at the following link which includes documentation: https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/trigger-an-event-11/

Answer (score 11):

You're now able to do:

```
var e = $.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 64});
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I need to say that sample from **Sionnach733** worked flawlessly. Some users complain about absent of actual examples. Here is my two cents. I've been working on mouse click simulation when using this site:  https://www.youtube.com/tv. You can open any video and try run this code. It performs switch to next video.

```
function triggerEvent(el, type, keyCode) {
    if ('createEvent' in document) {
            // modern browsers, IE9+
            var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
            e.keyCode = keyCode;
            e.initEvent(type, false, true);
            el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
        // IE 8
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.keyCode = keyCode;
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
    }
}

var nextButton = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-player-next')[0];
triggerEvent(nextButton, 'keyup', 13); // simulate mouse/enter key press
```

Answer (score 3):

For typescript cast to KeyboardEventInit and provide the correct keyCode integer

```
const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
          keyCode: 38,
        } as KeyboardEventInit);
```

Comment: The object is not matching the interface

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would draw your attention that in the specific context where a listener was defined within a jQuery plugin, then the only thing that successfully simulated the keypress event for me, eventually caught by that listener, was to use setTimeout().
e.g.

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#txtName").keypress() } , 1000);
```

Any use of `$("#txtName").keypress()` was **ignored**, although placed at the end of the `.ready() function`. No particular DOM supplement was being created asynchronously anyway.