# it is possible to programmatically click arrow keys in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to click programmatically arrow keys using javascript or jquery. I did not find a proper solution for that. Guys any ideas ? any examples ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event in JS/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery

Comment: What is it you're *really* trying to do by "clicking" the keys? It's likely there's a better way than trying to simulate an event.

Comment: i have a flash file.i load it inside html .it has few animations which are response to arrow keys. my intension is to programatically click arrow keys (according to logic) and animate . i don't have flash project so i can't change actionscript thats why im tring to do this.

Comment: @ErangaLakmalPerera You must use the allowScriptAccess="always" attribute to the object tag and use the script I've provided in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to trigger the events on the entire browser. But this is how you can trigger for individual elements on your page.

```
<body>
    <script>
       leftArrowKey = 37
       upArrowKey = 38
       rightArrowKey = 39
       downArrowKey = 40

       e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
       e.which = leftArrowKey;
       $("myInput").trigger(e);
    </script>

    <object allowScriptAccess="always" id="myInput" ... >
        ...
    </object>
</body>
```

To send this event to a flash animation, add allowScriptAccess="always" to the Object tag you are using.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that you were using this on a flash animation. I don't think this will work with flash. This was only meant for Html elements.

Comment: @ErangaLakmalPerera Please try out the new code I've edited my original code, to suit your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger click events by doing

```
$(selector).trigger('click');
```

Is that what you're looking for? http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: The title may be confusing, but he's aking about keypresses. You might get some negative votes, even though it's an incorrectly asked question.