# Simulate 'ENTER' Key Press Like Human Hit On Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, enter, simulate

Is it possible in Javascript/JQuery ?

I have a button on my website and I need to simulate human press key "Enter" when someone clicks the button.

Example:
I clicked button and then it automatically pressed Enter key.

Comment: Who marked this as duplicate? The questions are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I modified this code from the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368599/2640017),

```
var onclick = function(){
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 13; // Character 'A'
    $(this).trigger(e);
};

$('button').click(onclick);
```

You want to define a keypress event, define it as the <kbd>Enter</kbd> (13) keypress, and trigger it `onclick`.

Edit for new question: 
The keypress, keydown, and keyup events don't actually input anything, they're solely for triggering event bindings. You must also add the input if you want that as well. This line translates the keycode back to a string and appends it to the current value.

```
$("#test").val($("#test").val()+String.fromCharCode(e.which));
```

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/470/)

I also included two commented out lines of code that show two ways to submit the form programmatically.

```
$('#submit').click();
```

and

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/462/
There's no console log after click

Comment: @riko10 You missed a hashtag for the id selector. I changed $('test') to $('#test') > http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/464/

Comment: After click on submit I want to simulate click 'a' key (65) at input form. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/466/ Why 'a' doesn't display after clicking submit?