# How to simulate keypress to a textbox in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api

There are many similar topics in stackoverflow about this question, but it does not work for me.

I tried with Google Drive API tutorial at:

https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart#optional_view_a_quickstart_video

Now, I want to autotyping in textbox "Editor 1" and the textbox "Editor 2" will update.

I tried with:

```
document.getElementById("editor1").value = "ABC";
```

then the text changed, but the event does not recognized by Google Drive API, and the text of "Editor 2" does not change.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you very much

Comment: no, my question is not duplicated

Answer (score 4):

The answer is there:
[Trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event in JS/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery)

*I dont have reputation to ad this as comment*

Answer (score 0):

try jquery event i.e:

```
$("#editor1").keypress(function(){
    $("#editor2").val($(this).val());    // now you get the value of editor 1 in editor2
});
```

Comment: Not what's being asked. OP asks to simulate the keypress, not to listen for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

**HTML:**

```
Input 1: <input type="text" id="input1" onkeydown="myFunction()"/>
Input 2: <input type="text" id="input2"/>
```

**JS:**

```
function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("input1");
var y = document.getElementById("input2");
y.value=x.value;
}
```

And [here's the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a75ekc0e/7/).

Comment: There's no need to use jquery here.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers, but i am afraid that I described wrong. I want Google Drive API recognized the value change of the textbox, the Google Drive will update the value of the other textbox (not by using HTML or Javascript code). Tks so much

Comment: window.setInterval (function () {
 elm = document.getElementById ("editor1");
 elm.value = "avcddd";
 e = $.Event ('keyup');
 e.keyCode = 65;
 elm.trigger (e);
      }, 5000);

Comment: or you can see my code at: http://pastebin.com/cE0GcZ6J

Comment: and it does not work (the value changed, but the event keyup does not recognized)