# How to get a javascript keyboard behave like a real one

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I have an input field, and as soon as the user types something in it, I want something to happen, which worked fine with:

```
$('#my_input').on('keyup',function(e){
//my code 
});
```

Now I am using an on-screen keyboard from [here](https://github.com/sdeering/onscreenkeyboard) with which I can type stuff in the input field, however, my code never gets executed. It's like the on-screen keyboard is not recognized as a real keyboard. I also tried `change` and `input`instead of `keyup` without success and also this:

```
<input id="my_input" oninput="myFunction()" />

function myFunction(){
//my code
}
```

Anyone an idea how I could simulate this onscreen keyboard to be recognized as a real one?

**EDIT** full code:

```
<input id="my_input" />
<div id="virtualKeyboard"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsKeyboard.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

jsKeyboard.js I got from [here](https://github.com/sdeering/onscreenkeyboard/blob/master/jsKeyboard.js) and main.js from [here](https://github.com/sdeering/onscreenkeyboard/blob/master/js/main.js) 
jsKeyboard.js:

```
var jsKeyboard = {
    settings: {
        buttonClass: "button", // default button class
        onclick: "jsKeyboard.write();", // default onclick event for button
        keyClass: "key", // default key class used to define style of text of the button
        text: {
            close: "close"
        }
    },
    "keyboard": [], // different keyboards can be set to this variable in order to switch between keyboards easily.
    init: function(elem, keyboard) {
        jsKeyboard.keyboard["default"] = jsKeyboard.defaultKeyboard;
        jsKeyboard.keyboardLayout = elem;

        if (keyboard != null && keyboard != undefined)
            jsKeyboard.generateKeyboard(keyboard);
        else
            jsKeyboard.generateKeyboard("default");

        jsKeyboard.addKeyDownEvent();

         jsKeyboard.show();
         $(':input').not('[type="reset"]').not('[type="submit"]').on('focus, click', function(e)
         {
            jsKeyboard.currentElement = $(this);
            jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition = $(this).getCursorPosition();
            console.log('keyboard is now focused on '+jsKeyboard.currentElement.attr('name')+' at pos('+jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition+')');
         });
    },
    focus: function(t) {
        jsKeyboard.currentElement = $(t);
        jsKeyboard.show();
    },
    keyboardLayout: "", // it shows the html element where keyboard is generated
    currentKeyboard: "default", // it shows the which keyboard is used. If it's not set default keyboard is used.
    currentElement: null,
    generateKeyboard: function(keyboard) {
        var bClass = "";
        var kClass = "";
        var onclick = "";
        var text = "";

        var s = "";
        s += "<div id=\"keyboard\">";
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardHeader\">";
        // s += "<div onclick=\"jsKeyboard.hide();\"><span>" + jsKeyboard.settings.text.close + "</span><span class=\"closex\"> X</span></div>"
        s += "</div>";

        /*small letter */
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardSmallLetter\">";
        $.each(jsKeyboard.keyboard[keyboard].smallLetter, function(i, key) {
            generate(key);
        });
        s += "</div>";

        /*capital letter*/
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardCapitalLetter\">";
        $.each(jsKeyboard.keyboard[keyboard].capitalLetter, function(i, key) {
            generate(key);
        });
        s += "</div>";

        /*number*/
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardNumber\">";
        $.each(jsKeyboard.keyboard[keyboard].number, function(i, key) {
            generate(key);
        });
        s += "</div>";

        /*symbols*/
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardSymbols\">";
        $.each(jsKeyboard.keyboard[keyboard].symbols, function(i, key) {
            generate(key);
        });
        s += "</div>";

        function generate(key) {
            bClass = key.buttonClass == undefined ? jsKeyboard.settings.buttonClass : key.buttonClass;
            kClass = key.keyClass == undefined ? jsKeyboard.settings.keyClass : key.keyClass;
            onclick = key.onclick == undefined ? jsKeyboard.settings.onclick.replace("()", "(" + key.value + ")") : key.onclick;

            text = (key.isChar != undefined || key.isChar == false) ? key.value : String.fromCharCode(key.value);

            s += "<div class=\"" + bClass + "\" onclick=\"" + onclick + "\"><div class=\"" + kClass + "\">" + text + "</div></div>";

            bClass = ""; kClass = ""; onclick = ""; text = "";
        }

        $("#" + jsKeyboard.keyboardLayout).html(s);
    },
    addKeyDownEvent: function() {
        $("#keyboardCapitalLetter > div.button, #keyboardSmallLetter > div.button, #keyboardNumber > div.button, #keyboardSymbols > div.button").
            bind('mousedown', (function() { $(this).addClass("buttonDown"); })).
            bind('mouseup', (function() { $(this).removeClass("buttonDown"); })).
            bind('mouseout', (function() { $(this).removeClass("buttonDown"); }));

            //key focus down on actual keyboard key presses
            //todo:....

    },
    changeToSmallLetter: function() {
        $("#keyboardCapitalLetter,#keyboardNumber,#keyboardSymbols").css("display", "none");
        $("#keyboardSmallLetter").css("display", "block");
    },
    changeToCapitalLetter: function() {
        $("#keyboardCapitalLetter").css("display", "block");
        $("#keyboardSmallLetter,#keyboardNumber,#keyboardSymbols").css("display", "none");
    },
    changeToNumber: function() {
        $("#keyboardNumber").css("display", "block");
        $("#keyboardSymbols,#keyboardCapitalLetter,#keyboardSmallLetter").css("display", "none");
    },
    changeToSymbols: function() {
        $("#keyboardCapitalLetter,#keyboardNumber,#keyboardSmallLetter").css("display", "none");
        $("#keyboardSymbols").css("display", "block");
    },
    updateCursor: function()
    {
        //input cursor focus and position during typing
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.setCursorPosition(jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition);
    },
    write: function(m) {
        var a = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(),
            b = String.fromCharCode(m),
            pos = jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition,
            output = [a.slice(0, pos), b, a.slice(pos)].join('');
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(output);
        jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition++; //+1 cursor
        jsKeyboard.updateCursor();
    },
    del: function() {
        var a = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(),
            pos = jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition,
            output = [a.slice(0, pos-1), a.slice(pos)].join('');
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(output);
        jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition--; //-1 cursor
        jsKeyboard.updateCursor();
    },
    enter: function() {
        var t = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val();
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(t + "\n");
    },
    space: function() {
        var a = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(),
            b = " ",
            pos = jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition,
            output = [a.slice(0, pos), b, a.slice(pos)].join('');
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(output);
        jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition++; //+1 cursor
        jsKeyboard.updateCursor();
    },
    writeSpecial: function(m) {
        var a = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(),
            b = String.fromCharCode(m),
            pos = jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition,
            output = [a.slice(0, pos), b, a.slice(pos)].join('');
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(output);
        jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition++; //+1 cursor
        jsKeyboard.updateCursor();
    },
    show: function() {
        $("#keyboard").animate({ "bottom": "0" }, "slow", function() { });
    },
    hide: function() {
        $("#keyboard").animate({ "bottom": "-350px" }, "slow", function() { });
    },
    defaultKeyboard: {
        capitalLetter:
            [
        // 1st row
               { value: 81 },{ value: 87 },{ value: 69 },{ value: 82 },{ value: 84 },{ value: 89 },
               { value: 85 },{ value: 73 },{ value: 79 },{ value: 80 },
               { value: "Delete", isChar: "false", onclick: "jsKeyboard.del()", buttonClass: "button button_del", keyClass: "key key_del" },
        // 2nd row
               { value: 65, buttonClass: "button button_a" },{ value: 83 },{ value: 68 },{ value: 70 },
               { value: 71 },{ value: 72 },{ value: 74 },{ value: 75 },{ value: 76 },
               { value: "Enter", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_enter", onclick: "jsKeyboard.enter();", keyClass: "key key_enter" },
        // 3rd row
               { value: "abc", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_smallletter", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToSmallLetter();", keyClass: "key key_smallletter" },
               { value: 90 },{ value: 88 },{ value: 67 },{ value: 86 },{ value: 66 },{ value: 78 },
               { value: 77 },{ value: 44 },{ value: 46 },{ value: 64 },
        // 4th row
               { value: "123", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_numberleft", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToNumber();", keyClass: "key key_number" },
               { value: "Space", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_space", onclick: "jsKeyboard.space();", keyClass: "key key_space" },
               { value: "#%+", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_symbolsright", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToSymbols();", keyClass: "key key_symbols" }
            ],
        smallLetter: [
        // 1st row
                { value: 113 },{ value: 119 },{ value: 101 },{ value: 114 },{ value: 116 },
                { value: 121 },{ value: 117 },{ value: 105 },{ value: 111 },{ value: 112 },
                { value: "Delete", isChar: "false", onclick: "jsKeyboard.del()", buttonClass: "button button_del", keyClass: "key key_del" },
        // 2nd row
                { value: 97, buttonClass: "button button_a" },{ value: 115 },{ value: 100 },{ value: 102 },
                { value: 103 },{ value: 104 },{ value: 106 },{ value: 107 },{ value: 108 },
                { value: "Enter", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_enter", onclick: "jsKeyboard.enter();", keyClass: "key key_enter" },
        // 3rd row
                { value: "ABC", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_capitalletterleft", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToCapitalLetter();", keyClass: "key key_capitalletterleft" },
                { value: 122 },{ value: 120 },{ value: 99 },{ value: 118 },{ value: 98 },
                { value: 110 },{ value: 109 },{ value: 44 },{ value: 46 },{ value: 64 },
        // 4th row
                { value: "123", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_numberleft", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToNumber();", keyClass: "key key_number" },
                // { value: 32, buttonClass: "button button_space" },
                { value: "Space", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_space", onclick: "jsKeyboard.space();", keyClass: "key key_space" },
                { value: "#%+", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_symbolsright", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToSymbols();", keyClass: "key key_symbols" }
            ],
        number: [
        // 1st row
                { value: 49 },{ value: 50 },{ value: 51 },{ value: 52 },{ value: 53 },{ value: 54 },
                { value: 55 },{ value: 56 },{ value: 57 },{ value: 48 },
                { value: "Delete", isChar: "false", onclick: "jsKeyboard.del()", buttonClass: "button button_del", keyClass: "key key_del" },
        // 2nd row
                { value: 45, buttonClass: "button button_dash" },{ value: 47 },{ value: 58 },{ value: 59 },
                { value: 40 },{ value: 41 },{ value: 36 },{ value: 38 },{ value: 64 },
                { value: "Enter", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_enter", onclick: "jsKeyboard.enter();", keyClass: "key key_enter" },
        //3rd row
                // { value: "ABC", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_capitalletterleft", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToCapitalLetter()", keyClass: "key key_capitalletterleft" },
                { value: "", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_capitalletterleft", onclick: "", keyClass: "key" },
                { value: 63 },{ value: 33 },{ value: 34 },{ value: 124 },{ value: 92 },{ value: 42 },{ value: 61 },{ value: 43 },
                // { value: "ABC", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_capitalletterright", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToCapitalLetter();", keyClass: "key key_capitalletterright" },
                { value: "", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button", onclick: "", keyClass: "key" },
                { value: "", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button", onclick: "", keyClass: "key" },

        // 4th row
                { value: "ABC", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_numberleft", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToCapitalLetter();", keyClass: "key key_capitalletterleft" },
                { value: "Space", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_space", onclick: "jsKeyboard.space();", keyClass: "key key_space" },
                { value: "#%+", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_symbolsright", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToSymbols();", keyClass: "key key_symbols" }
            ],
        symbols: [
        // 1st row
            { value: 91 },{ value: 93 },{ value: 123 },{ value: 125 },{ value: 35 },{ value: 37 },
            { value: 94 },{ value: 42 },{ value: 43 },{ value: 61 },
            { value: "Delete", isChar: "false", onclick: "jsKeyboard.del()", buttonClass: "button button_del", keyClass: "key key_del" },
        // 2nd row
            { value: 95, buttonClass: "button button_underscore" },{ value: 92 },{ value: 124 },{ value: 126 },
            { value: 60 },{ value: 62 },
            { value: "&euro;", isChar: "false", onclick: "jsKeyboard.writeSpecial('&euro;');" },
            { value: 163 },{ value: 165 },
            { value: "Enter", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_enter", onclick: "jsKeyboard.enter();", keyClass: "key key_enter" },
        // 3rd row
            // { value: "ABC", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_capitalletterleft", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToCapitalLetter();", keyClass: "key key_capitalletterleft" },
            { value: "", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_capitalletterleft", onclick: "", keyClass: "key" },
            { value: 46 },{ value: 44 },{ value: 63 },{ value: 33 },{ value: 39 },{ value: 34 },{ value: 59 },{ value: 92 },
            // { value: "ABC", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_capitalletterright", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToCapitalLetter();", keyClass: "key key_capitalletterright" },
            { value: "", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button", onclick: "", keyClass: "key" },
            { value: "", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button", onclick: "", keyClass: "key" },
        // 4th row
            { value: "123", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_numberleft", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToNumber();", keyClass: "key key_number" },
            { value: "Space", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_space", onclick: "jsKeyboard.space();", keyClass: "key key_space" },
            { value: "ABC", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_symbolsright", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToCapitalLetter();", keyClass: "key key_capitalletterleft" },
         ]
    }
}


// GET CURSOR POSITION
jQuery.fn.getCursorPosition = function(){
    if(this.lengh == 0) return -1;
    return $(this).getSelectionStart();
}

jQuery.fn.getSelectionStart = function(){
    if(this.lengh == 0) return -1;
    input = this[0];

    var pos = input.value.length;

    if (input.createTextRange) {
        var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
        r.moveEnd('character', input.value.length);
        if (r.text == '')
        pos = input.value.length;
        pos = input.value.lastIndexOf(r.text);
    } else if(typeof(input.selectionStart)!="undefined")
    pos = input.selectionStart;

    return pos;
}

//SET CURSOR POSITION
jQuery.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
  this.each(function(index, elem) {
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  });
  return this;
};
```

main.js:

```
 $(function () {
     jsKeyboard.init("virtualKeyboard");

     //first input focus
     var $firstInput = $(':input').first().focus();
     jsKeyboard.currentElement = $firstInput;
     jsKeyboard.currentElementCursorPosition = 0;
 });
```

Comment: `myFunction != myFunction()` - change the `oninput="myFunction"` to `oninput="myFunction()"`

Comment: ok, this was a typo, I had it like you said, doesn't change anything, it's only listening to events from the keyboard not from the on-screen keyboard

Comment: I wasn't able to view the demo so I'm just going by a logical thought-process. If the keyboard is virtual, you have to click on the keys with your mouse. Can't you just use the **onmouseup** event?

Comment: Either of these questions may be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem is, with this keyboard that it gets generated after the site is loaded. So that's why none of the commands work.

A workaround is to use

```
$('body').on('click','.button',function(){
  $('input').trigger('keyup');
});
```

This

```
$('body').on('click','.button',function(){});
```

makes it possible to listen to a click event from a button class, even if it's dynamically loaded. And this will manually trigger the `keyup` event:

```
$('input').trigger('keyup');
```

which I got from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591484/oninput-event-for-jquery-onscreen-keyboard/35591600?noredirect=1#comment58869420_35591600)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Please use the below text. Function is always called as myfunction()

```
<script>
function myfunction() {
alert('');
}
</script>
<input id="my_input" oninput="myfunction()" />
```

[image]

Comment: yes, thanks, I had a typo, this doesn't change anything. It's only listening from events from a real keyboard

Comment: how do I verify that? it displays letters in the input field if I click on them

Comment: Can you please confirm if you have any code in your function which will be executed for this

Comment: yes, with this code, an alert will pop up once I use the OS on-screen keyboard or the physical real keyboard. But not the one I got form github

Comment: ok done, I posted the links to the scripts, is that ok? Thanks for taking the time!