# Why I cannot simulate keypress event?

Tags: javascript

I have tried next code on IE, Chrome, FireFox, it does not work;

I want just simulate entering the char on the the box.

Why it does not work as expected?

Could you help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example XHTML page</title>
    <script>
        function simulateKeyPress1() {
            var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
            if (document.implementation.hasFeature("KeyboardEvents", "3.0")) 
  {
                var event = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
                //initialize the event object
                event.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, false, null, 0,   
                                        false, 0, false, 77, 0);

                txt1.dispatchEvent(event);
            }            
        }

        function simulateKeyPress2() {
            //for Firefox only
            var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
            //create event object
            var event = document.createEvent("KeyEvents");
            //initialize the event object
            event.initKeyEvent("keydown", true, true, document.defaultView,  
                               false, false,true, false, 65, 65);
            //fire the event
            txt1.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="txt1" type="text"/>
    <p><button onclick="simulateKeyPress1()">SomeButton</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would this be a suitable answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery ?

Comment: Hi, I just study raw JS now, and want to do it without JQuery