# Javascript/React: Is it possible to trigger a keyboard *ENTER* event on an Input on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Input element that shows results only when I hit Enter from the keyboard. It's a third-party extension so don't have much control over it. What I want to do is that when I click a button, I want to trigger the *ENTER* event for the Input on the button click. Below is the code -

```
<input type="text" />
<button onclick = {**I want to bind enter keyboard event to the above input on this button click to show the search result**}>
```

Not sure if this is possible and if it is then will it be considered a bad coding standard? Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to set focus on the input field? If that then attach a ref on the input and call focus method of the DOM on click of button.

Comment: To raise an event create a custom event of KeyboadEvent with key as Enter and call input DOM's dispatch Event method to dispatch event for inout

Comment: More specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/38484217/3757232

Comment: @JaredSmith The answer given in this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483865/javascript-how-to-create-a-keypress-event  did not solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: @Mshah that is just the canned comment that the system posts when a user votes to close a question as a duplicate of another. If you do not feel that your question is a duplicate of the other and I have done so in error, please edit the original question with your case as to why and I will consider retracting the close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jared Smith's comment above provides the following solution:

```
onButtonClick() {
   const input = document.querySelector('inputSelector'); // or you can possibly use a ref here
   const e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    e.initEvent("keypress", false, true);
    e.keyCode = 13; // I believe 13 is the enter key
  input .dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

[edit] apparently `initEvent` is now deprecated in favor of `new Event`. see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

[edit2] I made a jsfiddle to show how `new Event` would work:

https://jsfiddle.net/pnwj97qs/

```js
const $input = document.querySelector('input');
$input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      const value = e.target.value;
      document.querySelector('.result').textContent = value + ' was entered';
    }
  })
  
const $button = document.querySelector('button');
$button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var e = new Event('keypress');
  e.key = 'Enter';
  e.keyCode = 13;
  $input.dispatchEvent(e);
})
```

```html
<button>simulate enter key</button>
<input type="text">
<div class="result"></div>
```

As you can see, I tie the behavior to the "Enter" key, and it works even when you press the button because of the `dispatch` event.

Comment: Hi! The code gives the Event Object, but this doesn't seem to work. I added setTimeout as well but it's not working. Any inputs? Thanks

Comment: You said you're using a library that waits for the `enter` event on the `input` element. I do'nt know anything about the library you're using and exactly how it's set up to listen for that event, so if this doesn't work, I do'nt know what will

Comment: @TKoL you are correct about keyCode 13 being enter, but keyCode i[s also deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) because the WhatWG hates us. It's `evt.key === 'enter'` now, which is great too because edge decided to use their own key text names rather than the standard. Woohoo!

Comment: @TKoL This solution works. Initially, it did not work due to the third-party library but I have resolved the conflict, and it's working now. Thanks!