# Fire multiple key events on iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, outlook.com

I have an outlook calendar shown in an Iframe, an i would like to change the view from month to day. 
To do this i need to press ctrl+shift+alt+1 but how do i make this happen on the iframe?

As you can see, i have tried to du this in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/methgaard/jtzd577f/)

```
document.getElementById('frame').onload = function() {
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 1; // # 1 code value
e.altKey = true; // Alt key pressed
e.shiftkey = true;
e.ctrlkey = true;
$("frame").trigger(e);
};
```

Can someone please tell me what to do?

Comment: In the fiddle it works perfectly for me. It is switching from month to day. First you click inside your iframe then press: ctrl+shift+alt+1. I am using google chrome

Comment: My mistake. I need this to happen automatically as the calendar will run on a monitor where this cannot be done manually.

Comment: [Look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery) This OP also wants to auto fire a keypress.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do however feel that is what I am trying already in my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/methgaard/jtzd577f/. Im not sure if the issue is with the keypress of with the focus or lifecycle of the Iframe