# Trigger a keypress with jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, triggers

When a user types into `#pgSearch` to filter a list, if there's no match, a `.noresults` becomes visable.
Also, when there's no match, a form (`#RequestRecipe`) should become visable as well. But it doesn't immediately when `.noresults` appears. I need to press any extra key to trigger it. Also vice-versa: when I delete characters till the `noresults` dissapears and the matches is displayed, but the form is still visible till I hit any extra key.
So my thought was to trigger a keypress. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(function(){
    $('#pgSearch').keyup(function() {
        $('#RequestRecipe #recipe').val($(this).val());  //  copy #pgSearch to #recipe
        $(this).trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 65}));  //  65 is for testing. I think 16 (shift) or 29 (ArrowRight) is suitable
        if($('.noresults').is(':visible')){
            $('#RequestRecipe').slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $('#RequestRecipe').slideUp('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT: I've uploaded a work-in-process version of my site where you can se what happens here : http://drinksta.thomaskile.me/
It's the search on the index-page.
When you star searching, the list is filtered using `quicksearch`-plugin.
When there's no match, the `.noresult`-row becomes visible (set to `display: table-row;`.
When this happens, you nedd to press an extra key to trigger the show/hide on `#RequestRecipe`.

Example:
you type "abc", the `.noresult` is shown, but not the form. You then have to either keep writing, or just pess any given key, and it then shows...

Comment: Can you show the same in fiddle ?

Comment: Have you tried `keydown` instead?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that fiddle-thing. It requires db-results, quicksearch-plugin...

Comment: @Roysh Yes. The same effect. It still requires an extra keypress to be executed.

Comment: see if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I have added a link so you can see and test...