# Searching on a datatable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to filter a datatable by setting the search input value to what I want to find:

```js
document.querySelector("#searchinput").value = $whatiwant;
```

The value is being set successfully, but it doesn't affect the datatable results. I tried to [submit it](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) (but it isn't a form, so it did't work) and to [simulate the enter key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery) (but it didn't work either and didn't return any errors). I also tried to use the [DataTables filter function](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()), but nothing seems to happen.

After all, what can I do to search/filter a datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Datatables API `search()`

> The global search is performed across all searchable columns

link: [search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search())

Example snippet code:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );
```

Or use API `column().search()` for specific column

> provides the ability to search globally across the table, this method,
>   and its plural counterpart, provide the ability to search for data on
>   a specific column.

link: [column().search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// #column3_search is a <input type="text"> element
$('#column3_search').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table
        .columns( 3 )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set searching:false in datatable options? you can set searching enable and disable from that option.

[datatables searching](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching)

You can enable searching by coding as follows. by doing this you don't need to add a separate input to search in datatable.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "searching": true
} );
```