# Mapbox Geocoder integration with on-screen keyboard

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I tried out this mapbox geocoding example:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/
in my application.

Now, I am trying to do the same thing, but instead of using a physical keyboard, I am trying to use on-screen keyboard like:
https://virtual-keyboard.js.org/

But at the moment, the inputs from the virtual-keyboard is not triggering the mapbox geocoder. How can I link the two components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the implementation of the `keyevent` function [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/22c35dd1db239e2fd435ddc678c37c89fd2885fd/lib/events.js#L79-L98) in the [`mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder) source code, the geocoder responds to [`keydown` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event), which are fired when a key is pressed.

The documentation for the virtual keyboard you linked includes an [`onKeyPress` method](https://franciscohodge.com/projects/simple-keyboard/documentation/#onKeyPress) to which you can pass a callback function to be executed when a key is pressed on the virtual keyboard. You can implement a function to simulate a `keydown` event (as described in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery)) equivalent to the last character from [`getInput`](https://franciscohodge.com/projects/simple-keyboard/documentation/#getInput). This should have the effect of triggering the geocoder as through an actual key was pressed.

Comment: Thank you Adriana. I used the method from the link below to generate the keydown event.

https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/trigger-an-event-11/