# How to simulate keyboard press "full stack" with JS?

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I've read and tried the solutions for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically) but none of them work as I expect.

In the code snippet below I register two event listeners and see both callbacks fire as a response to the `keydown` event on the `input` and `document`.

However, my expectation is that when this line of code runs there's an additional text entered into the input, `a`.

```
input.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

In other words, I expect that invoking `dispatchEvent` on the `input` element with `KeyboardEvent` as an argument should add text to the input, however it **does not**.

It **does** invoke the callbacks registered with the eventListener.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="input">

  <script>
    const input = document.getElementById('input')

    input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      console.log('Keydown on Input: ', e.key)
    })
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      console.log('Keydown on Doc: ', e.key)
    })

    function focusInputThenFireEventKeyboardEvents() {
      input.value = 'I want '
      input.focus()
      input.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
      input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'}));
      input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'a'}));
      var keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "a", char: "a", shiftKey: true });
      var keyEvent2 = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "d", char: "d", shiftKey: true });
      input.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
      document.dispatchEvent(keyEvent2);
    }
    setTimeout(focusInputThenFireEventKeyboardEvents, 500)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery)

Comment: @HassanMonjezi thank you for response. This one doesn't. The vanilla js solutions include a [deprecated api keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can check documentation here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent which says that keyboard event indicates user's interaction with key on keyboard and in order to handle text input you need to use input event. Even if you dispatch an event like const input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false})) it doesn't mean it will change the input but you can use it to programmatically set the value of input.