# JS Go to anchor tag's location on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 66) { 
    console.log(e.keyCode);
          $(".games .slick-current a:first-of-type").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

Right after selecting the first "a href", I want to automatically go to the anchor tag's `href` value. How can I do it?

Comment: You cannot automatically press a button on the Client's Computer, but you can `FormElement.submit()`. By the way `e.key === 'Enter'` is the modern test for Enter.

Comment: Well not a button but generate the "enter input". Perhaps what I mean is for example KEY + ENTER as a combo.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: `e = $.Event('keyup');
e.keyCode= 13; // enter
$('input').trigger(e);`

Comment: Font: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery by `cloakedninjas`

Comment: @Aks Jacoves Unfortunately not working, and the comment is what for ?

Comment: @SeitoKimbo What type of element matches `.games .slick-current a:first-of-type`? Is it a button or an input or a textarea etc ?

Comment: @Nate Levin It's a div.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo What do you want pressing enter to do?

Comment: @Nate Levin In my code thekeyCode == 66 which is B focuses and element on my page. I want the element to be focused AND entered at the same time.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo Do you mean you want a new line to be automatically typed in the div? Is the div `contenteditable`?

Comment: @Nate Levin I have a div with a link. When I press B, the link in the div is focused, but not clicked. I want to when I press B the link is clicked automatically. No the div is not contenteditable.

Comment: @Nate Levin When the link is focused, instead of the user pressing ENTER to access the link, I want ENTER to be pressed automatically right after he pressed B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the link is focused, instead of the user pressing ENTER to access the link, I want ENTER to be pressed automatically right after he pressed B.

What I get from this is that when the user presses `b` you want to send the user to the anchor tag's location.

This can be accomplished by setting `window.location` to the anchor tag's `href` attribute.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 66) { 
          $("#link").focus();
          window.location = $("#link").attr("href");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#scroll {
margin-top:140vh;
width:100%;
height:10vh;
background-color: red;
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#scroll" id="link">Press 'B' to open this link and scroll to the red box</a>

<div id="scroll">You scrolled to the red box.</div>
```

Comment: Yes YES exactly this. I don't know why nobody understood what I meant. Yes, focus and enter the link from a single function. Thank you so much ! Really struggled with this one.