# How to cover unit test case for addEventListener in Angular 9

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to cover the **addEventListener** internal code.

***any-angular.component.ts***

```
openModalWithKeypress() {
  const div = this.elm.nativeElement.querySelector('div');
  div.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    this.openModal(e);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can try to trigger a [keydown keyboard event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery) using dispatchEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your unit test in the [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) zone. Then, you need to invoke [`tick()`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick) just after dispatching the keydown `event`. This could look as follows:

```
it('#keydown should open modal', fakeAsync(() => {

  // given
  spyOn(anyComponent, 'openModal') 
  const divElement = <HTMLDivElement> fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('div');
  const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'x' });

  // when
  divElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  tick();

  // then
  expect(anyComponent.openModal).toHaveBeenCalledWith(event);
}));
```