# How can I press Tab key and Enter key on browser using browser's console?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, console, jquery-selectors

I want to press 2 buttons on the website one by one (by console code) but the click code doesn't work on one of them.

So instead, I am trying to make console code that presses Tab key and Enter key one after another on browser to press that button.

Here's what I want

1. Click one button (by console code)
2. Tab key (automatically by console code)
3. Enter key (automatically by console code)

-> so another button clicked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+trigger+button+tab+enter+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Hey, can you show code what you have tried ? Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery

Comment: I did document.querySelector('button').click() but don't know how to send Tab key and Enter key after this