# get key value press

Tags: jquery

I Want get key value on keyPress with jQuery In textbox

Comment: *None* of your other five questions received an acceptable answer? None? Mind you, if they all have this level of detail, people may not have tried very hard. The more effort you put into your questions, the better both the quality and quantity of the answers you'll receive.

Comment: I want people that write complete sentences and use question marks in questions.

Comment: Consider looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#textbox').keypress(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `keypress` event as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/); there's an example on that page showing how to get the key code:

```
$('#target').keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
   xTriggered++;
   var msg = 'Handler for .keypress() called ' + xTriggered + ' time(s).';
  $.print(msg, 'html');
  $.print(event);
});
```

You want the `event.keyCode` part.

[This page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) may also be useful, it describes some "gotchas" around cross-browser keypress handling. jQuery may smooth some of those out for you, but good to be aware of them.