# Calling my own function during with onClick

Tags: asp.net, jquery

How do I call a user-define function such as this one using the onClick attribute of a input button? More specifically what special steps must I take in JQuery and what would the HTML markup look like? Thanks

```
function simClick(keyCode) {
            var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
            e.keyCode = 8;
            $(document).trigger(e);
        }


<input type="button" ID="delBtn" class="calcBtn" value="Del" onclick="???????" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="button" ID="delBtn" class="calcBtn" value="Del" />
```

Javascript in separate file

```
  // When the DOM is ready
$(function() {
      // Function that is executed w keypress or button click
    doThis = function() {

        // Stuff to do
    }

      // To do when element with ID delBtn is clicked
    $("#delBtn").click(function() {

        // Stuff to do when input is clicked
        doThis();
    });

     // To do when key is pressed
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {

        // Stuff to do when key is pressed
        // Can check which key was pressed here.
        var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(code == 8) { //Enter keycode 

            doThis();
        }
    });
});
```

There are many ways to attach a handler to when that button is clicked. Take a look at **[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**.

You could also use the **[attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

```
$("input[value='Del']")...... // For the input with a value of Del
```

I'm not sure what you quoted JS has to do with the `input` button, since it looks like you're trying to work with a keypress instead of a click in that function.... But the above jQuery is how you capture a click on that `input` button.

Take a look at, **["Which key was pressed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)**

Comment: ahhh good question. I'm working on a little project that will detect key presses and execute code ... but i'm also using buttons to allow the less inclined to use a gui. so I basically am trying to reroute a button click to the same code i already have in place for detecting keypresses

Comment: @Matthew - Just call the same function with both. - edited answer.

Comment: so could someone help me visualize the structure here...

function myMethod()
{
}

$(document).keypress(function (event){

 myMethod();   
}

.. then what would I place here to bind the event handler and call myMethod? Forgive me but it's day two on JQuery and Javascript cominbed lol

function myMethod()
{
}

Comment: lol nm. i just extracted the code into a general method then called it in the keypress event and button click event ... newb central lol