# How to create a textarea with jQuery and/or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I need to create a textarea with jQuery and/or JavaScript.

I am using this code ( [`click here for preview`](http://jsbin.com/obuya3/) ) but backspace, enter, symbols and lowercase doesn't work. Why ?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>TEST</title>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            $(document).keyup(function (event) {
                var keyCode = event.keyCode;
                $('#mytext').text(function (i, text) {
                    return text + String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
                });
            });
        // -->
        </script>
        <style>
            #cmd {
                position: relative; 
                font-family: courier;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 5px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #mytext {
                float: left; 
                padding-left: 3px;
                white-space: pre;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cmd">
            <br>
            <div id="mytext">hello </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have those keys call a function to place html in between `<div id="cmd"></div>`

I could not find a keypress event function but it this should give you an idea

```
if (keycode==31) {
    $("#cmd").append("<br/>");
}
```

31 is code for enter.

Look here, they discuss jquery functions on keypress:
[jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Answer (score 0):

> For keydown and keyup events, you can
>   identify most common keys (letters,
>   numbers, and a few others) by just
>   looking at the event.keyCode and more
>   or less pretending that it is an ASCII
>   code. However, it isn't really, and
>   the many Javascript manuals that say
>   it can be converted to a character by
>   doing
>   "String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)"
>   are wrong. On keydown and keyup
>   events, the key codes are not
>   character codes, and this conversion
>   will give wild results for many keys.
>   There is no general portable way to
>   convert keycodes to characters. You
>   pretty much have to sense the browser
>   type and base the key mapping on that.

from http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Why don't you use a textarea with some styling?

Answer (score 0):

`return text + String.fromCharCode(keyCode);` appends a String to another string. Backspace and other control keys do not append strings, they do something with removing characters/moving caret. In this case, you should handle these keyCodes yourself. You can also designate the content as `editable`, then the browser handles all the control keys (like a WYSIWYG editor).

See: http://jsbin.com/obuya3/4 for an example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not about your question.

If you want to create a textarea with jquery, there are a lot of ways.

```
$("#cmd").append("");
```

Or you want use DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a HTML5, you can use "contenteditable" property.

Answer (score 0):

write this type of code Example of enter key this work fine

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  var key = event.which;
  var text = $('#mytext');
      if (key === 13) {
        $(text).append("<br/>");
     } else {
       $(text).append( String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
     }
});

http://jsbin.com/obuya3/8/edit
```